# Oldstyle numbers in body, newstyle numbers in section headings

Tags: sectioning, oldstylenums

I'm using the `eco` package to get oldstyle numbers in my manuscript, but I'm trying to get the section numbers (in the mainmatter and the table of contents as well) to be "newstyle numbers" (ie. lining figures) and having a tough time with it.

Can anyone shed some light on the matter please?

PS: It would be nice to get lining figures in the table and figure numbers as well.

Edit: posting a mwe below (regarding doncherry's suggestion).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{eco}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{section}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{subsubsection}}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{paragraph}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{subparagraph}}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{table}}}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents{}

  \part{One}
    \chapter{One--One}
      \section{One--One--One}
        \subsection{One--One--One--One}
          \subsubsection{One--One--One--One--One}
            \paragraph{One--One--One--One--One--One}
              \subparagraph{One--One--One--One--One--One--One}
              \subparagraph{One--One--One--One--One--One--Two}
              \subparagraph{One--One--One--One--One--One--Three}
            \paragraph{One--One--One--One--One--Two}
              \subparagraph{One--One--One--One--One--Two--One}
              \subparagraph{One--One--One--One--One--Two--Two}
              \subparagraph{One--One--One--One--One--Two--Three}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). 

Could you give a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Done! Sorry, didn't realize at first.

Comment: You can upload the picture (via the button) and remove the `!` from the beginning of the line. Then a higher-rep user will edit the post to display the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the font back to Computer Modern (`cmr`) for the relevant counters, similarly as `eco`'s `\newstylenumbers{}` does:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eco}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{section}}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{figure}}}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{table}}}

\begin{document}

% setting the counters to higher values just to see some more digits
\setcounter{page}{123}
\setcounter{figure}{455}
\setcounter{table}{788}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\section{Section 9876543210}

\begin{figure}[bh]
123456789
\caption{123456789}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Subsection 9876543210}

\begin{table}[bh]
123456789
\caption{123456789}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 9876543210}
\end{document}
```

The page numbers are still in old style figures, I couldn't change them, you didn't ask for that either. Numbers within section (etc.) titles and captions are still in osf as well.

[image]

---

Edit:

There's no need to redefine more than the highest level you're using, the changed font will be used throughout the *sectionlevel* number, you just need to get rid of the extra `{` and `}`, which form a group, limiting the scope of the changed font. Also, notice how they're all just a single number in your example, but should be like "1.1.1.1.1.1"? Just get rid of all redefinitions except `chapter` (and `table` and `figure` of course). Furthermore, the page numbers won't get pushed to the side if you put in an actual title and not an unknown and awkwardly long word like "One-One-One-One-One-One-One". Replacing the dashes `--` with spaces is sufficient:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{eco}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{section}}}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{subsection}}}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{subsubsection}}}
%\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{paragraph}}}
%\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{subparagraph}}}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{table}}}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents{}

  \part{One}
    \chapter{One One}
      \section{One One One}
        \subsection{One One One One}
          \subsubsection{One One One One One}
            \paragraph{One One One One One One}
              \subparagraph{One One One One One One One}
              \subparagraph{One One One One One One Two}
              \subparagraph{One One One One One One Three}
            \paragraph{One One One One One Two}
              \subparagraph{One One One One One Two One}
              \subparagraph{One One One One One Two Two}
              \subparagraph{One One One One One Two Three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the titles get longer than that, they'll be broken into several lines, but you might want to consider using a short title for the ToC then, using `\section[short title for ToC and header]{long title for the place in the paper where it actually appears}`.

Comment: Thanks! This _does_ get new style numerals on the section headings and the table of contents, but it _also_ messes up the toc's spacing between the section number and the section title. (I can't seem to figure how to post a code excerpt here, sorry :( )

Comment: It's new style numerals for the numbers (1, 1.1, 1.1.1), but not for the titles (9876543210). In this example, the spacing doesn't seem messed up; are you loading any other packages, a different document class or changing anything else that might have an influence here? If you want to post more than a few words of code, it's probably best to edit your question and to put it at its bottom.

Comment: (original question edited) :)

Comment: BTW, yes, it was indeed like that: lining figures for the "automatic" part of the sectioning, the section title's "text" is of no consequence.

Comment: It's lining ("new style") figures for the automatic numbering, old style figures for everything else.

Comment: I'd like _all_ of the numbers (ie. all of 1.1.1.1.2.3) to be lining figures, not just the very first one of them ;)

Comment: In that case, just apply the section-level numbering reset method to lower level commands as well. E.g., `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}`. Repeat for subsubsection, etc.

Comment: @Mico: Not necessary. mpr's comment was targeted at an [earlier version of my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/31948/3) where there was a superfluous pair of braces that limited the scope of the font change. I deleted two or three obsolete comments of mine. As it stands now, the font change prevails throughout the entire number chain, as you can see in the picture.

Comment: Superb! Thanks a bunch :)  - PS: in case of having subfigures / subtables, should one also strip the extra pair of braces from the \thefigure / \thetable redefinitions?

Comment: Two side notes: (a) if using `hyperref` you'll need to escape the content thus `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{chapter}.\texorpdfstring{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{section}}{\arabic{section}}}`  (b) in order to deal with appendices too, yuo'll need something along the lines of `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{chapter}.\texorpdfstring{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{section}}{\arabic{section}}}` _after_ `\appendix`, since this last one resets "sectionings". Hope it helps someone else! ;)