# Variable chapter references

Tags: cross-referencing, varioref

I'm looking to typeset certain references à la `varioref` thus so: if I reference chapter 3 from within chapter 2, I'd like the output to look like "...in the next chapter---" rather than "...in chapter 3 on page XXX...", similarly for sections, parts, etc.

Does anyone know of such a package or how I may go about tweaking `varioref` to suit my needs?

Comment: Does [touhami's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262086/8057) posted as a response to a related question work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an option you can try that uses the [`smartref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/smartref). We start off by called `\addtoreflist{chapter}` which defines the macro

```
\sgetchapterval{<macro>}{<lab>}
```

which stores the value of the chapter counter associated with label `<lab>` in `<macro>`. Then, using some `\ifthenelse` statements (provided by [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen)), we condition on whether the chapter reference is for the *previous* or the *next* chapter. If otherwise, we default to a [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) reference using `\vref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{smartref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/smartref
\usepackage{varioref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
\addtoreflist{chapter}% Provides chapter counter extraction
\newcounter{mychap}% Additional chapter counter

\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{%
  \sgetchapterval{\themychap}{#1}% Save chapter counter from reference in \themychap
  \setcounter{mychap}{\value{chapter}}%
  \addtocounter{mychap}{1}% Next chapter
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\mychap}{\themychap}}%
    {the next chapter}%
    {\addtocounter{mychap}{-2}% Previous chapter
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\mychap}{\themychap}}%
       {the previous chapter}%
       {Chapter~\vref{#1}}%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter} \label{chap:first}
See Chapter~\vref{chap:second} and Chapter~\vref{chap:last}. See \chapref{chap:second} or \chapref{chap:last}.
\chapter{Second chapter} \label{chap:second}
\chapter{Last chapter} \label{chap:last}
See Chapter~\vref{chap:second} and Chapter~\vref{chap:first}. See \chapref{chap:second} or \chapref{chap:first}.
\end{document}
```

I'm sure you could fine-tune this to your liking.

Comment: Hmmm... my PDFLaTeX is spiking 100% CPU when trying to compile your example into my manuscript... when killing it I get some `Missing \endcsname inserted` errors :S

Comment: I don't have that problem with `smartref 2002/02/28 v1.9` and `varioref 2011/10/02 v1.4z`.

Comment: possibly an outdated `hyperref`... I'm running TeXLive on Ubuntu... they're very anal about what gets to the distro :S

Comment: My MWE does not use `hyperref`, since non of the included packages use it.

Comment: I'm **very** sorry, I should have said so in the question... `hyperref` is to be loaded and supported (ie. the "next chapter" and "previous chapter" should be links rather than just text). I've been doing some testing on your code and found that it threw a lot of warnings if loading `smartref` _before_ `hyperref`, inverting the loading order seemed to fix it, but now the code does not work (it always says "previous chapter"). Again, I'm sorry, should I edit the question to reflect this fact or should I just close it and start a new one?

Comment: Th mistake was on _my_ side, too many hackish snippets. The answer wasrigh on the money.

Comment: I've been fiddling around with this piece of code and found that if you redefine `\thechapter` (in order to get, for instance [Oldstyle numbers in body, newstyle numbers in section headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/oldstyle-numbers-in-body-newstyle-numbers-in-section-headings)) this no longer works, outputting the `\vref` every time...

Comment: It seems that `smartref` is returning the formatted label text as the result of `\sgetchapterval`, which makes this solution incompatible with custom label formatting... do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'll have to look into this over the next couple of days. If it cannot be resolved in a reasonable amount of time, you could post a new question stating the connection to this one, including the new "oldstyle number" requirement. I think the Q&A as-is may be helpful in general, while yours is a specific case that may(?) require a different solution altogether.

Comment: A quick test with `hyperref` didn't yield anything fruitful. I would suggest wrapping it up here, asking a new question and referencing this one, since it may require a completely different strategy to incorporate *both* `hyperref` and oldstyle numbering.