# Relative chapter references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

(A follow-up of sorts on [Variable chapter references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32478/variable-chapter-references), as per @werner 's suggestion)

This is somewhere in between a request for comments and an actual question (as well as a summary of my experiences whilst trying to implement the linked question's idea to my personal liking, I hope someone else finds it helpful too).

The idea is (in the same spirit as the [`varioref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref)) to avoid redundancy and awkwardness whilst (hyper)referencing.

So, suppose you have a (hyper)reference to chapter 4 from within chapter 5, I'd like that to come out as (a linked up) *"the next chapter"* rather than *"chapter 5 on page XX"* (italics added for emphasis), analogously if you're referencing chapter 3 from within chapter 4.

Likewise, I'd like this mechanism to work for sections, subsections, etc. all the way down to subparagraphs.

### An initial solution

An initial (ie. considering `\chapter`s alone) solution to the problem was posted in the linked question above, and it basically boils down to:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{smartref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcounter{actualchap}
\addtoreflist{chapter}

\newcommand{\relref}[1]{
  \sgetchapterval{\targetchap}{#1}% Retrieve chapter counter from reference
  \setcounter{actualchap}{\value{chapter}}
  \addtocounter{actualchap}{1}% Next chapter
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\targetchap}{\theactualchap}}%
    {\hyperref[#1]{the next chapter}}%
    {\addtocounter{actualchap}{-2}% Previous chapter
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\targetchap}{\theactualchap}}%
       {\hyperref[#1]{the previous chapter}}%
       {\cref{#1}}%
    }%
}

\crefformat{chapter}{#2chapter~#1#3}
\Crefformat{chapter}{#2Chapter~#1#3}
```

Note that we're using the [`hyperref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), the [`smartref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartref), the [`cleveref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), and the [`xifthen` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xifthen).

### Digression / explanation

Why do we need *both* `smartref` and `cleveref`? Well, because we'd like to get all of this nice functionality without sacrificing (hyper)reference customization. Every other solution I could come up with eventually ended up doing (directly or indirectly) something along the lines of:

```
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{WHATEVER}
```

now, this breaks all of our carefully laid down `smartref` incantations: `smartref` relies on the `.aux` file containing *untainted* LaTeX references, whilst redefining `\thechapter` could make said entries contain LaTeX commands themselves (trying to get chapter numbers using `\oldstylenums` was a sure shot way of falling right into this), In other words: *formatting is happening too soon!* (it's present right there in the `.aux` file already)

If, on the other hand, we use `cleveref`exclusively (by using `cleveref`'s `\cref` command instead of LaTeX's `\ref` one), we can achieve the same effect (see the `\crefformat` and `\Crefformat` commands above, see `cleveref`'s documentation for an explanation on what the `#2` and `#3` parameters are and why do we need to define a capitalized and non-capitalized version of each) *without* ruining our other work: `cleveref` leaves laTeX's references alone, and *it only applies formatting at the very end!* (the second time LaTeX is run)

### Question proper

So, this is pretty sweet, but still, there's room for improvement (and my TeXnical skills are pretty much nonexistent besides some debugging and `.aux` file digging):

1. I'd like this same mechanism to work on sections, subsections, etc. (as stated above) *without* having to define different commands (ie. the `\relref` command above should be able of discerning on its own whether the reference it's given is to a chapter, section, subsection, etc.),
2. it should work on `*`ed sectioning commands as well,
3. it should play along nicely with `hyperref` whilst doing all of this (I see no reason why this could not be so).

So... longish question indeed, wanted to share the experience gathered nevertheless.

Have I tickled your interest? :)

Comment: I don't understand why you need `smartref` at all. Why not just use `cleveref` and `\cref'? (If you *really* don't want to change all your `\ref`s into `\cref`s, you can `\let\ref\cref` in your preamble. Though I recommend doing a search-and-replace \ref -> \cref in your source instead, to leave the original LaTeX `\ref` intact just in case.)

Comment: Does [touhami's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262086/8057) to a related question solve the issues mentioned here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question, I think you should be able to use the `\getreftype{..}` command [as defined here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33776/get-label-target-type) (`\getreftype{#1}` in your case) to discern the type of the reference that is the parameter of your function.

I think something like that should work :

```
\newcounter{actualelement}

\addtoreflist{chapter}
\addtoreflist{section}
\addtoreflist{subsection}
% ... and more

\newcommand{\relref}[1]{
    \csname sget\getreftype{#1}val\endcsname{\target}{#1}% Retrieve 'target' counter from reference
    \setcounter{actualelement}{\value{\getreftype{#1}}}% Current 'element'
    \addtocounter{actualelement}{1}% Next 'element'
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\target}{\theactualelement}}%
        {\hyperref[#1]{the next \getreftype{#1}}}%
        {%
            \addtocounter{actualelement}{-2}% Previous 'element'
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\target}{\theactualelement}}%
                {\hyperref[#1]{the previous \getreftype{#1}}}%
                {\cref{#1}}%
        }%
}

\crefformat{chapter}{#2chapter~#1#3}
\Crefformat{chapter}{#2Chapter~#1#3}
\crefformat{section}{#2section~#1#3}
\Crefformat{section}{#2Section~#1#3}
\crefformat{subsection}{#2subsection~#1#3}
\Crefformat{subsection}{#2Subsection~#1#3}
```

But no idea at this time for points 2 and 3 ...

Comment: Did you test your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I was using it a few times ago (december, I guess). But I just realised I forgot to link to the page with the macro `getreftype{..}` ! My bad.

Comment: I think you meant to link [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33870/call-macro-whose-name-depends-on-macro) ;)

Comment: @mpr you're right, I didn't remember exactly were I originally found the idea of this macro, and I have found the link I refered to in my history :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a *very* old question, but I'm screening for some known problems with cross-referencing and just found it, and I have (disclosure made) recently come up with a package which does just what you are asking for, and is actually more general, since you can do the same kind of relative reference to pages, and so on. It's called [`zref-check`](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref-check) and is based on `zref` (so it makes use of zref labels, not the standard ones, though you can make them work together to some extent, check the docs).

And it does match all of your requirements. In particular, it works for all sections and chapter, starred or not, and uses `hyperref` if you load it (this is configurable).

The UI concept is somewhat different than the regular reference commands (standard or of the most common packages): instead of trying to guess what should be typeset, `zref-check` lets you write what you want, and provides you with an easy way to get a warning at compilation if the statement you made no longer corresponds to the actual document as typeset.

A sample document using references to sectioning labels:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{zref-check}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\zlabel{cha:chapter-1}

\lipsum

\zcheck[nextchap]{sec:section-2.1}{on the next chapter}

\zcheck[nextsec]{sec:section-1.1}{on the next section}

\section{Section 1.1}
\zlabel{sec:section-1.1}

\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\zlabel{cha:chapter-2}

\lipsum

\section{Section 2.1}
\zlabel{sec:section-2.1}

\lipsum

\zcheck[nextsec]{sec:section-2.2}{on the next section}

\section{Section 2.2}
\zlabel{sec:section-2.2}

\lipsum

As discussed \zcheck[prevsec]{sec:section-2.1}{on the previous section}:
\lipsum[1]

But more of this \zcheck[nextchap]{cha:chapter-1}{on the next chapter} (this
is an incorrect reference, so you get a warning).

\end{document}
```

There is plenty more (a total of 22 defined "checks" available), but this is just making use of the kind of sectioning relations required by the OP.

Comment: I think this answer could use an update based on syntax changes for `\zcheck`. Nice package btw!

Comment: @mbert Ooops! I totally left this old answer hanging... Thanks for the reminder. Updated. And I'm glad you're enjoying the package.  ;-)