# Call macro whose name depends on macro

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, programming

Sorry about the title, I really couldn't find a better one.

I'm facing the following dilemma: I'm using the [`smartref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartref), in particular I'm using its `\sgetXval` macros. The thing is that I'm using the code kindly provided in [this previous question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33776/get-label-target-type) to determine whether a label points to (say) a section or a chapter, and I'd like to call either `\sgetsectionval` or `\sgetchapterval` accordingly.

I've tried with:

```
\csname sget\getreftype{#1}val\endcsname{\target@counter}{#1}
```

but I get `Missing \endcsname inserted` errors sistematically.

Bottom line: I'd like a way of *constructing* a macro name from an arbitrary expression and then call said constructed macro name.

I could post more code, but it's gonna get messy and I think this should suffice to convey the question proper, do let me know otherwise :)

Edit: MNWE ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{smartref}

\addtoreflist{section}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{actual@counter}% Additional chapter counter

% Helper macro to extract the type (section,subsection...) or the type name
% out of the label reference. Works with hyperref only.
% Argument #1 is a macro of form \def\...#1...\@nil{...}
% Argument #2 is the label reference, e.g. "sect:test"
\newcommand*\@getautoref[2]{% \HyPsd@@@autoref from hyperref, modified
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#2\endcsname\relax
    ??%
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@@getautoref
        \csname r@#2\endcsname{}{}{}{}\@nil#1\@nil
  \fi
}
\def\@@getautoref#1#2#3#4#5\@nil#6\@nil{%
  #6#4.\@nil}% Argument #4 = type and number, e.g. "section.1" or "subsection.1.2"

% \getreftype results in the type name, e.g. "section" or "figure".
% It remove a star, if existent, i.e. "section*" will become "section"
\newcommand\getreftype{%
  \@getautoref\@@getreftype}
\def\@getreftype#1.#2\@nil{#1}
\def\@@getreftype#1.#2\@nil{\@@@getreftype#1*\@nil}
\def\@@@getreftype#1*#2\@nil{#1}

% \getautorefname results in the type prose name (plus space character),
% e.g. "section" in English or "Abschnitt" in German
% (like \autoref, but without number).
% Since the \space is hard coded inside \HyPsd@@autorefname we use our
% own version called \@getautorefname instead.
% It will work with labels to \section* etc., too.
\newcommand*\getautorefname{%
    \@getautoref\@@getautorefname}
\def\@getautorefname#1.#2\@nil{\@@@getautorefname{#1}}
\def\@@getautorefname#1.#2\@nil{%
  \expandafter\@@@getautorefname\expandafter{\@@@getreftype#1*\@nil}}
\def\@@@getautorefname#1{% = \HyPsd@@autorefname without \space
  \ltx@IfUndefined{#1autorefname}%
    {\ltx@IfUndefined{#1name}{}{\csname#1name\endcsname}}%
    {\csname#1autorefname\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\getrefval}[2]{%
  \csname sget\getreftype{#1}val\endcsname{#2}{#1}% Retrieve chapter counter from reference
}

\begin{document}
  \section{An example section\label{sec:anExampleSection}}
  \section{Another example section\label{sec:anotherExampleSection}}

  \getrefval{sec:anExampleSection}{\csOne}
  \getrefval{sec:anotherExampleSection}{\csTwo}

  % here, \csOne should contain "1" and \csTwo should contain "2"
\end{document}
```

(this is a somewhat modified version of the code in the linked question, I didn't need the extra flexibility of having a starred and non-starred version of the macros defined therein, so I just deleted the corresponding code).

I get the error when trying to use `\getrefval`.

Comment: You probably just need an `expandafter` to make sure the macro inside the `csname` expands before the `csname` is created. If that doesn't work, could you add a full working example?

Comment: A MWE (well, non working) example would be better; but it sounds like `\getreftype` is not expandable, that is, it produces the necessary for *typesetting* the ref type, but not exactly the string (say `chapter`). However, `\getreftype` doesn't seem to be defined by **smartref**.

Comment: @egreg: Added MNWE :)

Comment: It's not complete: `\csname sget \getreftype{#1} val\endcsname{\target@counter}{#1}` is meaningless and `\target@counter` is unknown.

Comment: @egreg: very sorry about that, too much cut & paste and too little sleep. Corrected (I hope).

Comment: No, sorry: an example of usage is needed.

Comment: @wh1t3: No, `\csname` will expand its content fully, there is no `\expandafter` required. Only if the content doesn't expand finally to a text an error is raised.

Comment: @egreg: MNWE updated for sort-of usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the packages are loaded in the following order

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{smartref}
```

then the code does what's supposed to do. However the definition should be

```
\newcommand{\getrefval}[2]{%
  \csname sget\getreftype{#1}val\endcsname{#2}{#1}% Retrieve chapter counter from reference
}
```

without the spaces you were putting.

Moreover, `\addtoreflist{section}` has to be issued.

However, the same result can be obtained by loading the **refcount** package:

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\getrefval}[2]{%
  \edef#2{\getrefnumber{#1}}}
```

without any other code.