# How to use an environment whose name comes from a reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref

Suppose somewhere in my long Ph.D. thesis I use a theorem-like environment (maybe it's a theorem, maybe it's a lemma, etc.), and label it. At another place I want to have an environment which is the same as that earlier one (not with the same number though). I can get the environment's name with `cleveref`'s `\namecref` - but I can't just use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\label{myfirst}
This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{\namecref{myfirst}}
This is another environment of the same kind as \ref{myfirst}!.
\end{\namecref{myfirst}}
\end{document}
```

trying to `\def` or `\edef` something to the `\namecref` doesn't work either. What can I do? Of course, the environment cannot be known on the first run, so I would obviously need a macro which would expand to some 'dummy environment' on the first run and the real environment on the second (`\namecref` should give **??** on the first run which is not useful.)

*Note:* This questions is a lead-up to the question [Need a 'thin', flexible, theorem restatement environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39106/5640).

Comment: You have to extract the environment name from the label for yourself. Would you like to have a solution based on `hyperref` or a solution based on `cleverref`? (Both do store the environment name in the aux file, but in a different way.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: The best option would be a solution not based on any of them... otherwise, and if the solutions are short, then I'd like one for each of them; otherwise just for the one allowing the easiest solution.

Comment: "Not based on any of them" is IMHO the most difficult approach since one need to redefine `\label` for oneself, keeping this working with packages which redefine `\label`, too, especially `hyperref`. So I just posted a solution based on `cleveref` and one based on `hyperref`.

Comment: BTW: Why do you think "the best option would be a solution not based on any of them"? This just means writing extra code which already has been written by other persons and offered by other packages. IMHO this would be rather silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a hack, which is based on the existing `cleveref` implementation, which I'm not familiar with. It seems to work, but you may have to add a bit more robustness. (The solution is similar to one of Axel's solutions.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{reformulation}[1]
    {\expandafter\ifx\csname r@cref@#1\endcsname\relax% label undefined
         \def\my@env{theorem}% if label is undefined, assume it's a theorem
     \else%
         \cref@gettype{#1}{\my@env}%
     \fi%
     \begin{\my@env}}%
    {\end{\my@env}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \begin{lemma}\label{hi}
      Lemma.
   \end{lemma}
   \begin{reformulation}{hi}
      Theorem or lemma.
   \end{reformulation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are using `\edef\my@env{\csname cref@\@tempa @name\endcsname}`. IMHO `\cref@gettype{#1}{\my@env}` should be sufficient.

Comment: Hi Marc, I removed the salutation. This is just the style here, in order to keep things concise. See [the welcome message](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

One can use either `cleveref` or `hyperref` to get the "pure" name of the environment from the aux file. Unfortunately there are no documented ways on how to do it, so one has to use internal macros (which can change in future versions) in both cases.

First a solution for `cleveref`. It uses two internals from the `cleveref` package:

1. cleveref stores an additional label preceding with "cref@" to hold the environment name
2. cleveref offers an internal macro called `\cref@gettype` to get the "pure" environment name

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xxxref}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@cref@#1}%
    {\def\@xxx@env{quote}}% use default environment
    {\cref@gettype{#1}{\@xxx@env}}%
  \begin{\@xxx@env}}%
{\end{\@xxx@env}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\label{myfirst}
This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{xxxref}{myfirst}
\label{xxxfirst}
This is another environment of the same kind as \ref{myfirst}!.
\end{xxxref}
\begin{xxxref}{myfirst}
This is another environment of the same kind as \ref{xxxfirst}!.
\end{xxxref}
\end{document}
```

Second, a solution for `hyperref`. It uses two internals from the `hyperref` package:

1. hyperref stores the environment name inside the 4th argument of the label
2. The environment name is limited by a period inside that argument.

See also my answer here: [Get label target type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33776/get-label-target-type)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@myautoref[2]{% \HyPsd@@@autoref from hyperref, modified
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@@myautoref
      \csname r@#2\endcsname{}{}{}{}\@nil#1\@nil
}
\def\@@myautoref#1#2#3#4#5\@nil#6\@nil{% \HyPsd@autorefname, modified
  #6#4.\@nil}% Argument #4 = type and number, e.g. "section.1" or "subsection.1.2"
\def\@myreftype#1.#2\@nil{#1}

\newcommand*\beginref{\xxx@ref{\begin}}
\def\endref{\xxx@ref{\end}}
\newcommand*\xxx@ref[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#2}%
    {\def\@tempa{quote}}% use default environment
    {\def\@tempa{\@myautoref\@myreftype{#2}}}%
  \edef\@tempa{\noexpand#1{\@tempa}}%
  \@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\label{myfirst}
This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}
\beginref{myfirst}
This is another environment of the same kind as \ref{myfirst}!.
\endref{myfirst}
\beginref{xxxfirst}
This is another environment of the same kind as \ref{xxxfirst}!.
\endref{xxxfirst}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is the `\beginref` a `\newcommand*` while the `\endref` is a `\def`? Also, is there a reason not to define an environment, but rather just being and end macros?

Comment: Another question: You're using \cref@gettype as the pure name, while @MarcvanDongen's code uses `\csname cref@\@tempa @name\endcsname`. Is there a (potential) difference?

Comment: `\endref` is a `\def` since one can't define a new command starting with "end" using `\newcommand`. No, there is no reason not to define an environment. There was no wish given, so I implemented it as it first came into my mind. (In fact I even like an environment based solution.) And regarding the "@name" stuff: AFAIK this is for translation issues, so using `\csname cref@\@tempa @name\endcsname` is wrong. See also cleveref documentation, section "Language and babel support".

Comment: Addendum to last comment: `\cref@<type>@name` is the same as `\<type>autorefname` in `hyperref`, e.g. `\sectionautorefname` is "section" in English but "Abschnitt" in German, so `\autoref{..}` will give you an localized name, just like `\namecref{..}`.

Comment: Well, I suppose the non-hyperref and non-cleveref way is too long/complicated/brittle to use. Now, if I could only get the counter rather than the name, I could resolve [my followup question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39106/5640).

Comment: Where is the problem getting the number? It's the first argument of the label `\r@<label>`, and since it's not separated by a period or similar a simplified version of my hyperref solution for the name (taking the 1st argument instead of the 4th) will fit. As an alternative just take a look at the code for `\ref` in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: not the number, the name of the counter. But I'll have a look.

Comment: The name of the counter is usually the same as the name of the environment.

Comment: Usually is not always... `\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}`. Also, I accepted Marc's answer rather than your more comprehensive one since for cleveref it's about the same thing, and he wrote it first, and he needs the reputation more...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately usually is not always. But there is no generic solution to this :-(