# How do I determine the name of the counter associated with a theorem-like environment

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, counters, naming, ntheorem

(A question related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39286/5640) and leading up to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39106/5640).)

Suppose I'm using `ntheorem`. I would like to have a command which determines the name (not the value) of the counter associated with a certain theorem-like environment. Thus, the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\begin{document}
Propositions use the counter \getenvcounter{prop} while theorems use \getenvcounter{theorem}.
\end{document}
```

Should produce

> Propositions use the counter theorem while theorems use theorem.

I can tolerate the use of `cleveref` if necessary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\getenvcounter#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@getenvcounter\csname mkheader@#1\endcsname}
\def\@getenvcounter\csname#1\endcsname#2#3#4#5{#4}
\makeatother
```

Explanation: `\show\prop` gives

```
> \prop=macro:
->\let \thm@starredenv \@undefined \csname mkheader@prop\endcsname .
```

Then `\show\mkheader@prop` gives

```
> \mkheader@prop=macro:
->\csname setparms@prop\endcsname \@thm {prop}{theorem}{Proposition}.
```

So I expand twice `\csname mkheader@#1\endcsname`, which gives the token list shown last and define `\@getenvcounter` accordingly.

The version for the LaTeX kernel definition (kept by `amsthm`) would be

```
\makeatletter
\def\getenvcounter#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@getenvcounter\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\@getenvcounter#1#2#3{#2}
\makeatother
```

### Common version

If you prefer a version that doesn't depend on package loading, here it is:

```
\makeatletter
\def\getenvcounter#1{%
  \@ifundefined{mkheader@#1}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@getenvcounterkernel\csname#1\endcsname}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@getenvcounterntheorem\csname mkheader@#1\endcsname}}
\def\@getenvcounterkernel#1#2#3{#2}
\def\@getenvcounterntheorem\csname#1\endcsname#2#3#4#5{#4}
\makeatother
```

### Version supporting also `thmtools`

```
\makeatletter
\def\getenvcounter#1{%
  \@ifundefined{mkheader@#1}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@getenvcounterkernel
     \csname\ifcsname thmt@original@#1\endcsname thmt@original@\fi#1\endcsname}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@getenvcounterntheorem\csname mkheader@#1\endcsname}}
\def\@getenvcounterkernel#1#2#3{#2}
\def\@getenvcounterntheorem\csname#1\endcsname#2#3#4#5{#4}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use `cleveref`, then also loading `crossreftools` allows you to determine the counter in question by referencing just any one theorem-like environment by its label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{mythm}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}\label{just-a-prop}
And this is a proposition.
\end{prop}

My theorem uses the counter '\crtcrefcounter{mythm}' whereas my proposition uses the counter '\crtcrefcounter{just-a-prop}'.

\end{document}
```

[image: Use crossreftools to get counters associated with theorem-like enviornments]

The `crossreftools` package also works with `thmtools`. It includes other handy tools related to cross-referencing.