# Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?

Tags: packages, cross-referencing, incompatibility

Inspired by my earlier question [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict), here is another similar question.

There are many different packages for making cross references. Among them [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref), [`theoremref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/theoremref), [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref)… The [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package defines its own cross-referencing command for theorems…

Which collection of packages provides which kind of functionality, and which packages cause conflicts with each other?

Comment: It may not be what the asker intended, but I would love it if the answer included (in)compatibilities  with the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

### Preliminaries

In this answer, I'll be discussing how to go about creating cross-references to "objects" such as "Theorem 2", "Lemma 3", "Page 7", and "Section 4". Each object is assumed to be associated with a `\label` command; for instance, some important numbered theorem may be associated with `\label{thm:important}` and a numbered `\section` directive may be associated with `\label{sec:results}`.

### Classes of cross-references: Static, semi-dynamic, and fully dynamic

- **Static** or **hard-coded** cross-references. As the name "static" implies, these cross-references are hard-coded strings of the form `Theorem~2` and `Section~4`. Other examples are `in the next paragraph`, `in the final section`, and `the preceding lemma`.

  - Advantages:

    1. Trivially simple to implement.
    2. Requires no extra packages (or even TeX commands).
    3. Doesn't even require use of the `\label` commands. Extremely flexible.
  - Disadvantages:

    1. Requires a lot of care when first writing the document. For example, static references to the numbers of still-to-come equations, theorems, etc. can only be finalized after the rest of the document is completed.
    2. Serious risk of cross-references becoming stale or incorrect if the objects' *numbers* and/or *types* change later on. E.g., if an object named "Theorem 2" eventually becomes "Lemma 3", both the number and the type of the object are changed. The staleness risk is especially serious for cross-references to page numbers.
    3. Requires a willingness to do a lot of follow-up editing during the authoring process. Associated risk that this follow-up editing won't catch all required changes to the hard-coded cross-references.
    4. No built-in method for making these static cross-references into hyperlink targets should the author(s) wish to do so. (Actually, there *is* a way, via the `\hyperlink` and `hypertarget` commands of the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) package. However, it's much much easier to simply use `\label` and various `\ref` commands along with the `hyperref` package.)
- **Semi-dynamic** cross-references. These include the TeX/LaTeX `\ref` and `\pageref` commands. I call this method *semi-dynamic* rather than *fully dynamic* because it automates the *numbering* of the objects in question but hard-codes their types (`Theorem`, `page`, `section`, ...).

  - Advantages:

    1. Almost as simple as the (fully) static method.
    2. Avoids risks (1) and (2) of the static method, at least for the number part of the cross-reference.
    3. If only a few cross-references are needed in the document, this method is fully sufficient.
    4. By loading the `hyperref` package, the cross-references' numbers can be made into hyperlink targets as well.
  - Disadvantages:

    1. If you have cross-references to lots of objects at a time, say to "equations (2), (3), (5), (7), and (8)", typing all those `\ref{}` commands quickly becomes very tedious as well as error-prone.
    2. If you decide to change the *type* of an item being cross-referenced, say from "Theorem" to "Proposition", be prepared to do a lot of hand-editing of the hard-coded parts of the cross-references.
- **Fully dynamic** cross-references. Both the object's type *and* its number are generated by LaTeX.

  - Advantages:

    1. Avoid all risks noted above of the static cross-referencing method.
    2. Saves a lot of time when cross-referencing tasks are complex.
  - Disadvantages:

    1. Requires loading one or more additional LaTeX packages.
    2. Not all object types may already be defined by the package(s), requiring the author to add these object types by hand.
    3. Because the packages perform some fairly complex operations, there's a risk of unwanted interactions and incompatibilities with other LaTeX packages.

### Which packages provide which kinds of cross-referencing facilities?

- [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/). Provides the `\eqref` command to cross-reference numbered equations.

  There are two important advantages to typing `\eqref{eq:einstein}` instead of `(\ref{eq:einstein})`:

  1. You needn't remember to place parentheses around the cross-referenced equation number, and
  2. The output of `\eqref` (including the parentheses) is always set in an upright font shape. This feature is useful because cross-references to equations may occur in some text block that's set in italics (such as in the body of a theorem statement). By (near-universal?) convention, equation numbers and their parentheses should generally be typeset in an upright font shape regardless of the font shape of the surrounding text. It's quite handy not having to keep track of whether a cross-reference to an equation occurs in an italic text block or a "regular" (i.e., upright font shape) text block.
- [prettyref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/prettyref). Provides the command `\prettyref`.

  An important step towards fully dynamic cross-references. It works by relying on information contained in the object's `\label` to infer the object's type. However, this approach has some serious limitations. Quoting from its manual:

  > Labels in the document must be of the form `format:name` where the string `format` is used to determine the [object's type]. Do not use the character `:` anywhere within the label except to separate format from name. `format:name` must be unique for it is used as the label.

  In short, if you need to change the object's type from "theorem" to "proposition", you'll also need to change its label. This negates some of the advantages of using this package (in my view). A second problem can arise if the `babel` package is loaded with the option `french`, as this makes the `:` character "active" (in the TeX-specific sense of the word). For a work-around in case you need to load both `prettyref` and `babel-french`, see the query [prettyref bug when used with babel-french](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527909/5001) and especially [Enrico Gregorio's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527912/5001).
- [varioref](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/). Provides the commands `\vref` and `vpageref`. Its stated aim is to provide "intelligent page references." From the introduction of the package's user guide:

  > The `\vref` command refers to labels in the same way as does `\ref`, but if the thing referred to is on a different page, the result will be decorated with "on the facing page" or "on page ", and so on, as appropriate. The `\vpageref` command similarly decorates a page number; there are also commands `\vrefrange` and `\vpagerefrange` for ranges of labels.

  Very useful if you need to provide page location information automatically with each cross-reference.
- [smartref](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/smartref). This package partially extends the functionality of `varioref`, enabling not just the page of a `\label` to be recorded, but the value of arbitrary other counters (such as the present `chapter`).  This can be immediately used to add "in chaper N" to cross-references or, with some additional logic ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/relative-chapter-references)), to produce a `varioref`-style "in the next/previous chapter" call-out.
- [fancyref](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyref). Another step towards fully dynamic cross-referencing. Provides the commands `\fref` (and, for the beginning of a sentence, `\Fref`} for various pre-defined object types. It requires the use of specific label prefixes (e.g., `chap`, `sec`, `eq`, `fig`, etc.) to inform it about the object's type. Quite a few language-specific adaptations are available if it's used together with `babel`. Fully compatible with the `varioref` package.

  If you wish to add an object type -- say, "Lemma" -- to the list of object types that `fancyref` knows about, you may want to take a look at [Enrico Gregorio's brilliant answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100825/5001) to the question ["How to define a macro which declares a fancyref prefix? How to prevent it from outputting text?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100732/5001). Enrico provides a macro called `\mkfancyprefix` which lets users execute instructions such as `\mkfancyprefix{lem}{Lemma}`. This, in turns, lets users cross-reference lemmas (or is that *lemmata*?!) with an `\fref{lem:...}` instruction.
- [theoremref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/theoremref). As its name suggests, this package provides (fully dynamic) cross-references to theorems and related objects (lemmas, corollaries, etc.) Requires you to use the command `\thlabel` instead of `\label` to work. Functionality appears to be limited to theorem-like objects.
- [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/). When loaded with the `thref` option, this package provides a very elegant method for creating fully-dynamic cross-references to theorem-like objects. It even works if some of the objects share the same counter variable -- as is often the case with theorems, lemmas, corollaries, and propositions. Main user command: `\thref`.
- [hyperref](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/). In addition to providing its well-known capabilities for turning various cross-references -- both within a document and to objects outside the document -- into hyperlink targets, this package also provides the command `\autoref`. This command provides fully dynamic cross-references to a wide range of *single* instances of objects such as equations, sections, figures, tables, etc. A special aspect of this command is that the object's "name", e.g., "equation", is made a part of the hyperlink target, providing a large visual "target" for the mouse to click on and "jump" to the cross-referenced object.

  The "names" of the objects being cross-referenced with the `\autoref` command are, by default, in English. However, if the `babel` package is loaded with a suitable language option, `hyperref` will provide the objects' names in that language as well. As of mid-February 2020, available language options are (listed alphabetically) `afrikaans`, `catalan`, `dutch`, `english` (the default; synonyms: `UKenglish`, `british`, `USenglish`, and `american`), `french` (synonyms: `frenchb`, `francais`, `acadian`, and `canadien`), `german` (synonyms: `ngerman`, `austrian`, and `naustrian`), `greek`, `italian`, `magyar` (synonym: `hungarian`), `portuges` (synonyms: `portuguese`, `brazil`, and `brazilan`), `russian`, `spanish`, and `vietnamese`.

  In order for the `hyperref` package to work correctly, it is generally necessary to load it *after* all other packages that provide cross-referencing functions. The exception to this rule is the `cleveref` package -- see below.
- The [memoir](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) document class: Provides commands `\tref`, `\fref`, `\pref`, etc to create dynamic cross-references to tables, figures, pages, etc. (Note that the `memoir` command `\Cref`, which is used to create cross-references to chapters, is incompatible with that of the `cleveref` package.) Use of these cross-referencing commands is great for the intelligibility of the LaTeX code. The obvious cost is a proliferation of cross-referencing commands. Wouldn't it be nice to have to remember only a very limited number of cross-referencing commands?!
- [cleveref](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref). The current "king" of all cross-referencing packages. Main user commands: `\cref` and `\crefrange` (and the uppercase variants `\Cref` and `\Crefrange` for use at the start of a sentence).

  - In addition to doing lots of fancy behind-the-scenes footwork to create fully-dynamic cross-references, the `\cref` command can take not just one argument but *many* arguments. These arguments needn't be sorted by the author -- the package will do that for him/her! -- and they needn't even be of the same type, i.e., you can issue the command `\cref{thm:this,lemma:that,prop:here,cor:there}` and `cleveref` will automatically create a lexically correct group of cross-references for you.

  [image]

  ```
      \documentclass{article}
      \usepackage{amsthm}
      \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
      \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
      %% Define several theorem-like environments:
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
      \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
      \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
      \newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}

      \begin{document}
      %% Create a few dummy instances of the theorem-like environments:
      \begin{theorem}     \label{thm:this}   \end{theorem}
      \begin{lemma}       \label{lemma:that} \end{lemma}
      \begin{proposition} \label{prop:here}  \end{proposition}
      \begin{cor}         \label{cor:there}  \end{cor}
      \begin{proposition} \label{prop:where} \end{proposition}
      \begin{theorem}     \label{thm:what}   \end{theorem}

      \noindent % Now, use a single \cref command to cross-reference them.
      \Cref{thm:this,lemma:that,prop:here,cor:there,prop:where,thm:what}.
      \end{document}
  ```

  - If you have theorems, lemmas, corollaries, propositions, and other environments that *share a common counter* variable, the `cleveref` manual suggests that you load either the `ntheorem` or the `amsthm` package prior to defining these theorem-like environments (and also prior to loading `cleveref`, obviously). The `ntheorem` and `amsthm` packages provide some very handy auxiliary, behind-the-scenes information that helps `cleveref` figure out which name (theorem, lemma, corollary, etc) to associate with the object being cross-referenced, even if the environments share a common counter.
  - Extensive language adaptations. The document's language, if different from English, has to be specified as an option when the `cleveref` package is loaded. (`cleveref` is compatible with `babel` as well.) As of late-2016, the package can adapt the names of cross-referenced objects to the following 14 [!] languages: `brazilian`, `catalan`, `danish`, `dutch`, `english` (default), `esperanto`, `french`, `german`, `italian`, `norwegian`, `russian`, `spanish`, `swedish`, and `ukrainian`. Toby Cubitt (the author and maintainer of the `cleveref` package) actively welcomes submissions of object names for additional languages.

    An interesting tidbit of information regarding the rendering of the names of these objects: In English, there is no declension of nouns (including those used in cross-references), i.e., their form is the same whether the noun is used in the nominative, genitive, dative, accusative, etc form. This simplicity, however, does not apply to many other languages. :-( The `cleveref` package's singular and plural noun forms are all in the nominative form; if you use the package with a language other than English (or, I suppose, French, Spanish, and Italian), you should use the command `\creflabel` instead of `\cref`, and provide the appropriate case of the noun yourself, if the noun isn't being used in its nominative form. Even though you have to supply the name of the noun yourself when you use the `\creflabel` command, you still get to benefit from the sorting and compression facilities of the `cleveref` package.
  - Virtually all aspects of the cross-references can be customized fully.
  - The manual of the `cleveref` package recommends loading the `ntheorem` package with the `thref` option if you're going to create cross-references to theorem-like objects (especially if the objects share the same counter).
  - The `cleveref` package is fully compatible with other packages that provide cross-referencing commands -- including `varioref`, `ntheorem`, and `hyperref` -- *as long as `cleveref` is loaded last*.
  - Some caveats when using the `cleveref` package:

    1. The package is seriously incompatible with the `showonlyrefs` option of the `mathtools` package. By "seriously incompatible" I mean that if `cleveref` is loaded together with `\usepackage[showonlyrefs]{mathtools}`, not only will the `\cref` commands containing labels of equation objects be messed up, but many other cross-referencing packages will also experience major problems. Fortunately, this problem appears to be the only incompatibility between the `cleveref` and `mathtools` packages.
    2. If both the `footmisc` and the `hyperref` packages are loaded, there are some unresolved incompatibilities that affect cross-references to footnotes. This problem also affects a variety of other packages that provide cross-referencing functions, including `cleveref`.
    3. If your document loads the `babel` package with the option `french`, be sure not to use the `:` ("colon") character in the arguments of any `\label` and `\cref`-family instructions. This is because (a) the `babel-french` combination makes the `:` character "active" and (b) `\cref` needs to perform various operations on its argument; these operations will crash if the `:` character is active.

### Addendum: Further cross-referencing possibilities

A major limitation of the cross-referencing mechanisms currently provided by the LaTeX kernel is that the `\label` command only writes *two items* to the `.aux` file: the value of the *counter* that was last incremented by a `\refstepcounter` or similar directive, and the number of the *page* on which this `\label` instruction is recorded. This limitation makes it impossible, for instance, to easily write something like "As was shown by Theorem~xx in Section~yy", as LaTeX doesn't provide a method for associating information about the theorem's number with the number of the section in which the theorem appears. The `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages apply some nifty hacks to the LaTeX kernel to overcome this limitation at least partially. However, these hacks aren't all that robust; this lack of robustness explains in part why these two packages should generally be loaded *last*.

The [zref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) bundle of packages created by Heiko Oberdiek aims to overcome this limitation, by providing both an interface for macro programmers and several packages that make use of this interface. The package doesn't modify the basic `\label`, `\ref`, and `\pageref` commands. Instead, it provides the commands `\zlabel` and `\zref`, where `\zlabel` can be programmed to generate several rather than just two pieces of information to be written to the `.aux` file, and where options can be passed to `\zref` to specify which piece(s) of information should be cross-referenced.

To the best of my knowledge, so far none of the major cross-referencing packages (including `hyperref`) make use of the power afforded by the `zref` package. However, there are several smaller packages or "modules", also written by Heiko Oberdiek, that demonstrate some of the potential uses of the `zref` approach. For instance, the module `abspage` makes possible referencing the *absolute* page number of a document. This is useful for documents (including many books!) that have both roman-style and arabic-style page numbers: The macro `\zref[abspage]{LastPage}` references the *total* number of pages in the document, irrespective of the numbering styles that may be in use.

Comment: You forgot to mention that `cleveref` (unfortunately) has some problem if you are using more than one language in your document. Also, you have forgotten Heiko Oberdiek’s `zref`, which can totally replace `ref` and gives you unlimited possibility to build you own referencing system. It is included in the `oberdiek`-bundle.

Comment: @Sveinung - thanks for drawing my attention to the `zref` package. I must confess I'm not familiar with it, but I'll definitely look into it now. Would you mind being a bit more specific as to the problems that `cleveref` has "if you are using more than one language in your document"? Thanks.

Comment: This is documented at page 18 in the manual. Fortunately, you can use `csquotes` `\hyphenblockquotes{<language>}{<cited text>}` in your quotes.

Comment: @Sveinung - The multi-language issues you raise don't seem to be unique to `cleveref`, but may be shared with other packages that depend on interfacing with `babel`'s language-switching commands. The package's author strongly recommends  using `\documentclass[<language(s)>]{<class>} followed by `\usepackage{babel}` and, eventually, `\usepackage{cleveref}`. If cross-reference names are customized by the user, it is recommended to do so via via "hooking the redefinitions into babel's language switching mechanism." Have you experienced problems or crashes with this approach? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, I have experienced that my reference keyword has been in wrong language. `csquotes` does not have this problem, so I can enclose the foreign language in a `\hyphenblockquote`. It is worth mentioning because it surprised me in an agreement I wrote in English, where had an enclosure in Danish. The  reference word (section) was in Norwegian in the English text, because I use `memoir` with `article` option, and in the preamble I have redefined the `cleveref` keyword `chapter` to `section` (in Norwegian) (I try to make my template multi language).

Comment: @Sveinung - Thanks for sharing these experiences. I think having examples of such first-hand experiences is very useful. I only ever have one additional language (beside English) to deal with, so this is clearly an area I haven't spent much time (or experienced many frustrations) with. Have you contacted Toby Cubitt with your experiences and asked for his advice on how to alleviate some of the problems? Just a thought.

Comment: @Sveinung - at long last I've gotten around to providing an additional part to this (already very long) answer, to bring up the `zref` package and its potential uses.

Comment: +1 Great post. Now, I think I'm going to adopt `cleveref` and leave `prettyref` behind...

Comment: @Mico, has the status of `zref` changed since you posted this? Any hope for a more robust `zref`-based `cleveref` replacement any time soon?

Comment: @Gaussler - I'm afraid I don't have informed answers to your questions. AFAICT `cleveref` is pretty robust as it is. I honestly don't know why `zref` hasn't caught on more.

Comment: Of possible _additional_ interest: 1. to refer to `indexed words`: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393821/how-to-refer-to-indexed-words/393843#393843], 2. to control the `case of the initial letter in the referred  title`: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392567/how-to-control-the-case-of-the-first-letter-of-a-referred-title] and [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393442/how-to-completely-control-the-case-of-the-first-letter-of-a-referred-title]

Comment: Another downside that, unfortunately, I discovered recently is the uncompatibility between cleveref and refcheck , a great package that finds unused labels in your document.

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo - Do you load `refcheck` before or after `cleveref`?

Comment: @Mico I load refcheck after cleveref, but it doesn't matter the order, this is a known issue. Here there is a (partial) workaraound: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87610/making-refcheck-work-with-cleveref

Comment: Regarding your first commentary about `cleveref`:       "you can issue the command `\cref{thm:this,lemma:that,prop:here,cor:there}` and `cleveref` will automatically create a lexically correct group of cross-references for you."        This is not entirely true: for example, if the first reference is a lemma (labeled lem) and the second is a theorem (labeled thm), then `\Cref{lem,thm}` gives "Lemma 1 and theorem 2", so `Cref` does not capitalize the first letter of 'theorem'. Do you know how to fix this, other than using "`\Cref{lem}` and `\Cref{thm}`"? Thanks.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas - I disagree with your assertion that the claim in the sentence you quoted is "not entirely true": The claim I made was about the *lexical structure* of `\cref`'s output, not about capitalization rules; I stand by this claim. Anyway, if you want to uppercase the first letters of "lemma", "theorem", "proposition", etc, you should probably be loading the `cleveref` package with the option  `capitalize`. (`capitalise` works too.)

Answer (score 42):

### hyperref compatibility

The `hyperref` package redefines many macros of LaTeX and LaTeX packages for generating hyperlinks in documents, for many kinds of references, such as citations, footnotes, captions, table of contents entries, and bookmarks. That's why it should usually be loaded after other packages, with some exceptions, such as some of the following packages which also offer cross-referencing features. See: [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

- `nameref`: is compatible, it is part of the `hyperref` bundle. It can be loaded before `hyperref` or after it.
- `prettyref`: works with `hyperref`, load it before `hyperref`

  ```
    \usepackage{prettyref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
  ```
- `titleref`: works, option `usetoc` not recommended

  ```
    \usepackage{nameref}
    \usepackage{titleref}% without usetoc
    \usepackage{hyperref}
  ```
- `varioref`: partially supported, load it before `hyperref`

  ```
    \usepackage{nameref}
    \usepackage{varioref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
  ```
- `cite`: From version 5.0 on, compatible to `hyperref` and `backref`. Earlier versions are incompatible, there's a workaround in the `hyperref` README file.
- `cleveref`: compatible, load it after `hyperref`

  ```
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
  ```
- `amsrefs`: compatible, load it after `hyperref`

  ```
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{amsrefs}
  ```
- `ntheorem`: provides certain compatibility with `hyperref` via the `hyperref` option, and it has to be loaded before `hyperref`:

  ```
    \usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
  ```
- `memoir`: compatible

### cleveref compatibility

From the manual:

> The `cleveref` package enhances LaTeX's cross-referencing features,
> allowing the format of cross-references to be determined automatically according to the "type" of cross-reference (equation, section, etc.) and the
> context in which the cross-reference is used.

`cleveref` should be loaded after all other packages in order to avoid problems.

- `hyperref`: is compatible, it supports also the `backref` option
- `nameref`: is compatible
- `titleref`: is compatible
- `varioref`: is supported, `cleveref` redefines some macros
- `fancyref`: not supported, `cleveref` offers enhanced features
- `ntheorem`: unsupported, but `cleveref` redefines `ntheorem`'s`\thref`
- `memoir`: compatible

Comment: `cite` claims compatibility with `hyperref` from version 5.0: `Hyperref and backref compatability!` (`cite.sty`, version 5.3, line 753)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks! I added that. Edit or edit suggestions would also be fine.

Comment: `cleveref` is incompatible with the `showonlyrefs` option of the `mathtools` package. Fortunately, this seems to be the only incompatibility between these two very useful packages.

Comment: `clearref` rewrites several `amsmath` internals in order to do its thing, but afterwards `mathtools` cannot do its thing. I've suggested the AMS to have a chat with the `cleverref` author about adding some hooks into `amsmath` such that `cleverref` no longer need to be so invasive. Other than adding hooks into `amsmath` I have no idea how to make `mathtools` and `cleverref` more compatible.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: Maybe you can have a look at [refstyle](http://ctan.org/pkg/refstyle). It DO NOT rewrite any Latex internal and only uses '\ref' and '\pageref'. It is therefore (in theory) compatible with most packages. It has multi-langual suppourt. Because of these points it is now the base reference system of LyX

Answer (score 29):

### Package functionality

The functionality provided by the various packages for cross-referencing may be divided as follows:

- Formatting references according to the type of label being referred to (i.e., typesetting "section 3" instead of only "3"). Packages like [`fancyref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyref), [`prettyref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prettyref) or [`refstyle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refstyle) provide a semi-automatic solution as you must adhere to certain name prefixes for labels or use type-specific reference macros. Fully automatic solutions are offered by [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) and [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).
- Sorting and compressing sequences of referenced labels. This seems to be only available with `cleveref`.
- Referring to a label's name instead its number (e.g., a sectioning title or the caption of a float). This is done by, e.g., [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) and [`titleref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleref).
- Typesetting "intelligent" page references (i.e., "on the previous page" instead of "on page 2" for a reference at page 3). This is the main feature of [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref).
- Adding hyperlinks to cross-references. This is (surprise) the uncontested domain of `hyperref`.

All of the packages listed above are "general-purpose" (i.e., work for labels of any type). Other packages like [`theoremref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/theoremref) or [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) provide some of the above functionality, but only for theorems.