# achemso stopped generic Tables, Figure and Eq. in front of labels

Tags: achemso

I have the following problem. After an update to MikTeX2.9 (from 2.7) the [`achemso`](http://ctan.org/pkg/achemso) package stopped working properly in terms of generating "key words" in front of labels used by `\re`f. I.e. now instead of "See Figure 1" I have just "See 1". Does anyone have any idea what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that is 'by design'. The longer answer is that [`achemso`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso) used to load [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) to do the 'auto-magic' change of references. However, this package has some load order requirements with other material, and these have over time made it very difficult to maintain `achemso` such that the load order issues did not cause problems for users. It reached a point where the only way to ensure that other stuff worked was to drop loading `cleveref` entirely. You can of course load this in your document yourself, as this then leaves you having to deal with the load order requirements.

Comment: For more on reference package conflicts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/215