# Bold cross references

Tags: cross-referencing, bold

I'm writing my PhD thesis in LaTeX and I have a lot of figures - each one is referenced within the text. So I have:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
...
...
\label{fig:stuff}
\end{figure}
```

then, later, in the text:

```
blah blah blah this is shown in \ref{fig:stuff}, which indicates blah blah
```

and I get:

```
blah blah blah this is shown in Figure 2.7, which indicates blah blah
```

I want to make "Figure 2.7" bold - I'm loading the caption package with the `labelfont=bf` option so that it's bold in the caption of the figure itself, but I'd also like it to be bold in the text. I guess I could do this with

```
blah blah blah this is shown in \textbf{\ref{fig:stuff}}, which indicates blah blah
```

but ideally I'd like not to have to change multiple references to all 71 figures...

Any ideas?

Comment: Just from a typographic point of view: I don't think this is a good idea, as it will optically emphasize your references very much and make it stand out of the grey value of the text.

Comment: Some journals want you to emphasize the first occurrence of a figure reference in bold (not all). This is probably more difficult to achieve it automatically.

Answer (score 16):

I assume that you want to **bold-face** your cross-references to make them stand out strongly in the text. However, this is a dubious practice from a typographic point of view. Rather than bold-facing the cross-references, I'd suggest that you make them into hyperlinks that can be assigned a color. To do this, start by loading the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package with the `colorlinks` option set. Then, use the `\autoref` command that's provided by the `hyperref` package to create colored hyperlinks to the objects being cross-referenced. Note that the `\autoref` command is what one might term fully dynamic: it typesets both the *type* (such as equation, figure, table, section, etc.) and the *number* of the cross-referenced object. By using the `\autoref` command, the hyperlink "target" (the part that's colored) will be highly visible, because it consists of both the type and number of the item being cross-referenced.

An even more flexible and powerful cross-referencing command than `\autoref` is `\cref`, provided by the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package; I suggest that you load the `cleveref` package the `nameinlink` option set. (Even if you do use `\cref`, I still recommend you also load the `hyperref` package with the `colorlinks` option set. If you load both `hyperref` *and* `cleveref`, be sure to load `hyperref` first.) Like `\autoref`, `\cref` is fully dynamic; the `nameinlink` option forces the link to consist of both the item's type and number. Unlike `\autoref`, `\cref` lets you create cross-references to *multiple* items of the same type (e.g., equations) and even multiple items of differing types all in one cross-referencing command; the `cleveref` package will nicely sort and typeset the cross-references being generated without the user having to worry about such details.

For much more on various cross-referencing commands and packages in general, and the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages in particular, see the answers to the question [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

Comment: The twelfth upvote on this answer gave me 120K total reputation points. Many thanks to everyone who uses this great site!

Answer (score 7):

Just redefine `\ref`:

```
\let\origref\ref
\def\ref#1{\textbf{\origref{#1}}}
```

Comment: If `hyperref` is loaded this is dangerous; it's better to say `\LetLtxMacro{\latexref}{\ref}` (it needs the `letltxmacro` package).

Comment: Surely.  My answer is a quick hack which breaks a lot of things...

Comment: Instead of redefine `\ref`, why not define a new one: `\newcommand{\bref}[1]{\textbf{\ref{#1}}`?

Comment: This also works, but if you have a long doc with \refs, it might be easier to redefine \ref.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Fallino is almost right, but it allows only for *either* the types ("Figure", "Table", "Section"...), *or* the labels to be bold. Example:

```
In \cref{sectionname} we review the initial conditions ...
```

Leads to different output depending on the lines in the preamble.

**Case 1**

```
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textbf{#1}#3}
```

results in:

[image: Only the label has boldface]

**Case 2**

```
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{\textbf{Section}}{\textbf{Sections}}
\Crefname{section}{\textbf{Section}}{\textbf{Sections}}
```

results in:

[image: Only "Section" has boldface.]

**Case 3**

```
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textbf{#1}#3} % <-- Only #1 in \textbf
\crefname{section}{\textbf{Section}}{\textbf{Sections}}
\Crefname{section}{\textbf{Section}}{\textbf{Sections}}
```

gives the desired look

[image: Both "Section" and the label number are bold.]

Comment: In general it's better to provide full examples, not just fragments of code. Please elaborate on your solution

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can add in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} % load after hyperref package
\crefdefaultlabelformat{\textbf{#2#1#3}} % boldface only the number

% boldface only the type in front of the number
\crefname{figure}{\textbf{Figure}}{\textbf{Figures}} 
\Crefname{figure}{\textbf{Figure}}{\textbf{Figures}}

% BONUS
\crefname{table}{\textbf{Table}}{\textbf{Tables}}
\Crefname{table}{\textbf{Table}}{\textbf{Tables}}
\crefname{appendix}{\textbf{Annexe}}{\textbf{Annexes}}
\Crefname{appendix}{\textbf{Annexe}}{\textbf{Annexes}}
\crefname{section}{\textbf{\S}}{\textbf{\S}}
\Crefname{section}{\textbf{\S}}{\textbf{\S}}
\crefname{algorithm}{\textbf{Algorithme}}{\textbf{Algorithmes}}
\Crefname{algorithm}{\textbf{Algorithme}}{\textbf{Algorithmes}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Quarto, for some reason I had to do a mix of the answers above

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} # Allows \cref{} to cite latex table as "Table 3"
# Specify which cross-reference should automatically be bolded : Tables and Figures
# Use \cref{} ; For some reason this only works with this exact disposition :
# Only #1, nameinlink and each of the reference specified. namelink + #1#2#3 would give an error.
- \crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textbf{#1}#3} # <-- Only #1 in \textbf
- \crefname{table}{\textbf{Table}}{\textbf{Tables}}
- \Crefname{table}{\textbf{Table}}{\textbf{Tables}}
- \crefname{figure}{\textbf{Figure}}{\textbf{Figures}} 
- \Crefname{figure}{\textbf{Figure}}{\textbf{Figures}}
```