# How to define a macro which declares a fancyref prefix? How to prevent it from outputting text?

Tags: macros, fancyref

In a LaTeX document, I use the `fancyref` package for in-document references. However, I need a bunch of custom prefixes to reference lemmas, definitions and theorems, which fancyref dos not provide. Following the documentation, adding a prefix which supports both `vario` and `plain` for both `fref` and `Fref` takes a lot of text, and it's all the same all the time. I'd like to avoid this using a macro which does it all for me, and I got stuck with that.

Here's my current attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[plain]{fancyref}

% command to define a fancyref prefix
\makeatletter
\def\mkfancyprefix#1#2{%
  \@namedef{fancyref#1labelprefix}{#1}%
  \frefformat{plain}{\@nameuse{fancyref#1labelprefix}}{%
    \MakeLowercase{#2}\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1%
  }%
  \Frefformat{plain}{\@nameuse{fancyref#1labelprefix}}{%
    #2\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% environments and references for lemmas, ...
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\mkfancyprefix{lem}{Lemma}

% content
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
\label{lem:lemma}
This is a Lemma
\end{lemma}
There's \fref{lem:lemma} around! \Fref{lem:lemma} is the same, but at the beginning of a sentence.
\end{document}
```

However, this fails to compile, complaining about a:

```
Missing \begin{document}
```

If I move the `\mkfancyprefix{lem}{Lemma}` after `\begin{document}`, I can see that it actually outputs `fancyreflemlabelprefixfancyreflemlabelprefix`. Other than that, everything works and looks as expected.

This confuses me a lot, why does the command print the expanded arguments of `\@nameuse` to the document? I did some experimenting and added `\expandafter` immediately before both occurrences of `\@nameuse`. That changes the output to `lemlem`, which does not reduce my confusion.

Why does it do that, and how can I prevent it?

Addendum:
Enrico provided  [a great answer to my question below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100825/5001). Expanding this a little yields the a command which declares a new `fancyref` prefix in the format variants `vario` and `plain`. If you use others (like `main`), you have to extend the macro accordingly.

```
\makeatletter
\def\mkfancyprefix#1#2{%
\expandafter\def\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname{#1}%
% plain lowercase
\begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\frefformat{plain}}%
    \expandafter\x\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname
    {\MakeLowercase{#2}\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1}%
% plain uppercase
\begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\Frefformat{plain}}%
    \expandafter\x\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname
    {#2\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1}%
% vario lowercase
\begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\frefformat{vario}}%
    \expandafter\x\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname
    {\MakeLowercase{#2}\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1##3}%
% vario uppercase
\begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\Frefformat{vario}}%
    \expandafter\x\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname
    {#2\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1##3}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: The second argument of `\frefformat` needs to be a csname which `\@nameuse` only gives after two expansions. `\@nameuse{foo}` first expands to `\csname foo\endcsname` and then to `\foo`

Comment: Have you considered using the `cleveref` package instead of `fancyref`? The `cleveref` package should have predefined names for all of the objects you mention.

Comment: @cgnieder: I also tried putting `\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname` but then it says `Extra \endcsname.`

Comment: @Mico: Unfortunately, `cleverref` can not automatically print the page reference the way `fancyref` does: Using "on the next page", leave it away when it is on the same page, and the page number otherwise.   (Also, sorry for adding three comments here and constantly editing them, somehow it wouldn't let me add a newline in a comment, and automatically post it as the browser looses focus, which I did not expect)

Comment: @RalfJung `\csname ...\endcsname` should work together with an `\expandafter` chain

Comment: @cgnieder: I changed the `\@namedef{...}` to `\expandafter\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname`. Now the macro works again without using `\@namedef`, but it still produces output: `lemlem`. Should I edit the question? Also, I don't know what an `\expandafter` chain is, and after some searching I have the impression it's about adding `\expandafter` in many places, but I can't seem to figure out the right ones. Not do I even understand what I am doing.

Comment: @RalfJung - Re the use of `cleveref` instead of `fancyref` while also making use of the capabilities of the `varioref` package: You could type something like `as shown by \cref{type:descript} \vpageref{type:descrip}`. (Here, `\vpageref` will create an "intelligent" cross-reference to the page number.) This is admittedly not as elegant as modifying/augmenting some of `fancyref`'s capabilities directly. But, depending of course on what you need to get done, the `\cref`/`\vpageref` combination may be good enough to satisfy to your typesetting needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `\frefformat` expects its second argument to be a control sequence, not the instructions to produce one; so you have to build the token before TeX sees `\frefformat`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\mkfancyprefix#1#2{%
  \@namedef{fancyref#1labelprefix}{#1}%
  \begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\frefformat{plain}}%
    \expandafter\x\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname
      {\MakeLowercase{#2}\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1}%
  \begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\Frefformat{plain}}%
    \expandafter\x\csname fancyref#1labelprefix\endcsname
      {#2\fancyrefdefaultspacing##1}%
}
\makeatother
```

The `\x` trick is just to be able to use `\expandafter`.

How does it work? When `\mkfancyprefix{lem}{Lemma}` is called, TeX does

```
\@namedef{fancyreflemlabelprefix}{lem}
```

which is equivalent to `\def\fancyreflemlabelprefix{lem}`. Then it finds

```
\begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\frefformat{plain}}%
  \expandafter\x\csname fancyreflemlabelprefix\endcsname
    {\MakeLowercase{Lemma}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
```

(the `##1` in the definition of `\mkfancyref` now becomes `#1` as it should). After doing the `\def\x{...}`, LaTeX still has a `\begingroup` pending and finds `\expandafter\x`, so it expands `\csname fancyreflemlabelprefix\endcsname` (once), which produces the token `\fancyreflemlabelprefix`. Next `\x` is expanded, so TeX is confronted with

```
\endgroup\frefformat{plain}\fancyreflemlabelprefix
  {\MakeLowercase{Lemma}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
```

The `\endgroup` matches the still pending `\begingroup` and removes the definition of `\x` from memory; then the correct `\frefformat` instruction is ready for being processed.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second revision of this answer is working great, both in the MWE and in my actual document (the first one consumed the space after `\fref{lem:lemma}` for some reason). And the explanation is very helpful. :)

Comment: @RalfJung I too was surprised because of the missing space. I really don't know why this happens, but the current version seems good.

Comment: This is brilliant! I'll add a link to this answer in my answer to the question about cross-referencing commands.

Comment: @Mico: I use this command to also declare the `vario` type formats (which are used by `fancyref` per default), but I omitted that from the question to keep it simpler. However, for your overview, the full command would IMHO be more helpful. Maybe even `main` should be added. How should that be handled? (I wanted add that as command over there, but somehow I can't)

Comment: @RalfJung - Providing a full example that lets the user make use of both the `fancyref` and `varioref` packages would certainly be useful. You could provide an addendum to your question, in which you provide such a code snippet. I'll happily mention this code in my answer about cross-referencing packages.

Comment: @Mico: You mean, editing the question to include the answer? This does not sound right to me, but of course I am new here.

Comment: @RalfJung - A simple restatement of Enrico's solution as an addendum to your answer wouldn't be the way to go. However, if you explain in the addendum that you're providing a solution that goes beyond what you asked for originally, and if you explain that you're providing a solution that makes the (augmented/modified) `\fref` commands work nicely with `varioref`, I think you'd be providing some useful additional information.