# Using table number in the text

Tags: tables, numbering

Latex takes care of the number of tables by itself. Like it will automatically number the table as `Table 4` etc. I want to use this number in the text.

For example, if I write "See Table 4" and later on I insert one more table above it then `Table 4` becomes `Table 5` but my text still says `Table 4` which is inconsistent.

Comment: You need to insert `\label{name}` after the table caption and then you can refer to the table by `\ref{name}` in the text. LaTeX will take care of updating the number. You will need to compile the document twice to get the referencing right.

Comment: When a structural change in the document occurs that affects the numbers of sectioning headers and floats, be sure to recompile *twice* so that all cross-references are fully updated. For a general discussion of LaTeX cross-referencing methods see, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36312/5001.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest to have a look at [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTex2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf), in particular Section 2.8, which explains cross referencing.

In short, you need to define a label for your table, and later on reference this label to have an always updated number. It looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Some & text
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The caption of the table}\label{table:somename}
\end{table}
In text, I can reference the Table~\ref{table:somename} like this.
\end{document}
```

You need to run `latex` twice to get the reference mechanism correct.