# In the hyperref-pkg, is there a way to (sometimes) use abbreviations; e.g. tab. _vs_ table?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, naming

"Manually", both of the following do the trick (as far as I can tell):

```
\ldots as presented in table~\ref{tab:birds_and_bees} \ldots

\ldots as presented in tab.~\ref{tab:birds_and_bees} \ldots
```

With the `hyperref`-pkg, "only" the following seems to be on offer:

```
\ldots as presented in \autoref{tab:birds_and_bees} \ldots
```

which produces the long version of "table" (*not* the abbreviated tab.).

I guess it'd be o.k. to use `\autoref{tab:birds_and_bees}` sometimes, and `tab.~\ref{tab:birds_and_bees}` at other times (in the same document ! ), but is there a way of having the abbrev. done via `hyperref/autoref`, too?

PS: one disadvantage of using `tab.~\ref{tab:birds_and_bees}` is that the "tab."-part is *not* linkified (not "blue", in my output). IMO, it looks beta if "tab." is blue, too.

PPS: for in-depth discussion (providing *many* pointers and food for thought): [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36295/cross-reference-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict)

Comment: You may want to look up the `prettyref` package for that.

Comment: @kan do you know if the two pkg's (`hyperref` & `cleveref`) can both be loaded in the same document without causing trouble? (am asking cuz I'm using a template I didn't write and I don't want to "break things", as it were)

Comment: @Jubobs do you know if the two pkg's (`hyperref` & `prettyref`) can both be loaded in the same document without causing trouble? (am asking cuz I'm using a template I didn't write and I don't want to "break things", as it were)

Comment: I think loading both works fine, but keep the cleveref last.

Comment: @kan you mean load it *after* loading hyperref (in the preamble)?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Yes.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Yes. I use `prettyref` in conjunction with `hyperref` all the time. Make sure to load the latter after the former.

Comment: @Jubobs: so kan suggests 1) `hyperref` 2) `cleveref`; and you suggest the converse loading sequence: 1) `prettyref` 2) `hyperref` ? (just doesn't seem all too consistent, but I'm inclined to believe you both :)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I don't use `cleveref` myself but I've read elsewhere it must be loaded after `hyperref`. However, you must load `prettyref` (if you decide to use it) *before* `hyperref`.

Comment: @kan Ok, I've fallen for `cleveref`, if you turn your comment into an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty For the answer to be of help to others, would you mind giving me a table, so that I can post an answer? (I am too lazy to type up one.)

Comment: @kan am rushing towards a deadline (and am not too apt in TeX yet); if that's ok I'll get back to you/this Q&A soon? ps: notice I added a link as pps to my question; perhaps this question ought to be closed-as-too-localized?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Arbitrary text can be linked with the optional argument form of `\hyperref`:

```
\hyperref[tab:birds_and_bees]{tab.~\ref*{tab:birds_and_bees}}
```

The star form `\ref*` generates a reference without a link to prevent a nested link.

Also `\autoref` can be configured:

```
\renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{tab.}
```

If you are using package `babel` then this is language dependend, e.g.:

```
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{tab.}%
}%
```

See also the manual of `hyperref`.