# Reference entire title of a Theorem, not just its number

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems, amsthm, ntheorem

Say I have

```
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:Fermat}
This is a theorem about Fermat.
\end{theorem}
```

and the output is **Theorem 5.2.** *This is a theorem about Fermat.*

Now I want to reference it by `\ref{thm:Fermat}`, but this only returns `5.2` and not `Theorem 5.2`. What can I do to make it return `Theorem 5.2` ?

I found the `ntheorem` package with `\thref`, but using the ntheorem package my theorem-sytles do not seem to work anymore (i.e. I would have to rewrite all of them). Could I  circumvent this issue somehow? But perhaps there is an easier solution? A potentially small example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `cleveref` package? this should solve your problem.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36312/5001.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the [`cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) package for this, as you can use the regular `\label` command and customize the appearance of the reference very easily using `\crefname` and friends.

You might like the reference to appear differently when referencing the theorem at the beginning of the sentence, or midway through a sentence- `cleveref` allows for this easily.

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
% each of the following has two versions
%   \crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used mid-sentence
%   \Crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used at the beginning of a sentence
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:Fermat}
    This is a theorem about Fermat.
\end{theorem}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \Cref{thm:Fermat} is very good.
    \item And also \cref{thm:Fermat} is very good.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there also a package/method that uses both the regular `\label` and regular `\ref` ?

Comment: @Tom not as far as I know, and there might be some unforeseen dangers in changing `\ref`

Answer (score 6):

If you only need theorem referencing (and no figure, table, listing etc.), you can use the [`theoremref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/theoremref) package. The latest version on CTAN is already compatible with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, theoremref, hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\thlabel{thm:Fermat}
This is a theorem about Fermat.
\end{theorem}
\thref{thm:Fermat} is very good.
\end{document}
```

Another option is the `\autoref` command from `hyperref`. For more flexible solutions, see [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36295/cross-reference-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict).