# How to cross-reference several objects simultaneously

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, compiling

I want to define a macro for referencing equations in an article. I want the equation to be referenced as: " Eq. (3) "
So I defined a command "\eref{}" as:

`\def\eref#1{Eq.~\ref{#1}}`

But I also have instances where I want to refer to multiple equations like: "Eq. (3,4,5)" and when I try to use:

`\eref{label1,label2,label3}`

I simply find " Eq. ?? " in the pdf.

Can anyone kindly help me declare a macro which can take as input a list and simply call another function with that list (like how `\ref{}` command of latex does). I tried to replace "#1" in the definition by "##", it didn't work.

I wish to have similar macros for referring to Lemmas, Theorems, etc, which too have similar problems.

Comment: I suggest you to look at the `cleveref` package.

Comment: I think you might look into the `cleveref` package, which does all of this already

Comment: Aside: I suppose you are using LaTeX - then don't use `\def`; use `\newcommand` et.al.

Answer (score 3):

If you have three consecutive equations labeled, say, `eq:1`, `eq:2`, and `eq:3` and need to cross-reference them jointly, you could do so with the help of the `cleveref` package and its `\cref` command:

```
\cref{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3}
```

`cleveref` is clever enough (pun intended) to sort and, if necessary, compress the numbers associated with the equations, generating the typeset output "eqs. (1) to (3)". If you don't want to see the word "equations" abbreviated to "eqs.", load the `cleveref` package with the `noabbrev` option.

The only real restriction if using the `cleveref` package is that you mustn't use a comma (`,`) as part of a label's name since -- as you can tell from the example above -- commas are used to separate labels from one another.

For much more on the topic of cross-referencing, including various aspects of the `cleveref` package, see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) and the associated answers.

Comment: Does `cleveref` package have any conflicts with `hyperref`, because i used `\cref{label1,lebel2}` and it simply gives: " ???? " in the pdf.

Comment: @PavithranIyer - The `cleveref` package must be loaded *after* `hyperref`. Also, be sure to compile the document twice to let LaTeX update and resolve all cross-references.

Comment: Thanks. The `\cref` command for referencing one equation fits with the format I needed. However for multiple labels, it seems to place a "and" in between the references. Moreover, when I try to extend `\cref` to Lemma and Theorem environments as: `\crefformat{lemma}{Lemma.~(#2{}#1{}#3)}`. I loose the parenthesis around the equation number in the reference (pdf) when I call `\cref` with multiple labels.

Comment: @PavithranIyer - The connector "and" will be used if there are two items of a type being cross-referenced. Please consider posting a *new* question and providing an explicit MWE (minimum working example) to ask for advice on how to format cref-type cross-references to additional objects (such as theorems and lemmas).