# Editing cleveref's format for multiple label references

Tags: macros, formatting, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using the `cleveref` package to refer to theorems, equations, etc, in an article (LaTeX). I wish to have the format of reference as:
Thm. (1) for single theorem (or equation, figure, etc) and Thms. (1,2) for a pair of (theorem) labels.

To achieve my required format with `cleveref` I do:

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{theorem}{Thm.~(#2{}#1{}#3)}
\crefname{theorem}{Thm.}{Thms.}
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ ,~}
```

However, I am not quite able to achieve the format required for the case where I have a pair of labels -- I require the counters in the reference to be enclosed by "(" and ")" parenthesis:

> Thms. (1.1, 1.2)

Can anyone please help me modify the format for multiple labels case ? Since some had asked for a MWE, here is one:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{theorem}{Thm.~(#2{}#1{}#3)}
\crefname{theorem}{Thm.}{Thms.}
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ ,~}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\section{\today}

Here is a sample theorem:
\begin{theorem} \label{thm-something}
Define something \dots
\end{theorem}

Here is another sample theorem:
\begin{theorem} \label{thm-some-other-thing}
Define some other thing \dots
\end{theorem}

I do not want references in this format: \cref{thm-something,thm-some-other-thing}

I want to enclose the counters by ``('' and ``)'' parenthesis. So it should be: ``Thms. (1.1, 1.2)''.
\end{document}
```

I have edited this question based on comments on its previous posting.
(This question is a continuation of [How to cross-reference several objects simultaneously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136271/how-to-cross-reference-several-objects-simultaneously) )

Comment: can you give us a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to play with?

Comment: You say you want something like `Eqs. (1,2,3)` to be the result of cross-referencing the first three equations. What should be the result when cross-referencing equations 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12: Should it be `Eqs. (7--12)` or `Eqs. (7,8,9,10,11,12)`? Please advise.

Answer (score 8):

The command `\crefformat` is meant for defining the formats of cross-references to single instances of an equation, a figure, a theorem, etc. To set up the formatting for a cross-reference to a range of items, you need to work with `\crefrangeformat`. The following setup may suit your needs:

```
\crefrangeformat{equation}{Eqs.~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangeformat{figure}{Figs.~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangeformat{theorem}{Thms.~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
```

Be sure to use the command `\crefrange{<first-label>}{<last-label>}` when referring to ranges of labels.

By the way, you seem to have a lot of pairs of curly braces , `{}`, in your `\crefformat` instructions. These pairs probably aren't necessary.

Comment: This works, but still leaves the case with multiple labels that are not in range. For e.g. `\cref{eq1, eq4}`

Comment: @kksagar - Well, I'm sure relieved that you believe that my answer "works." My answer addressed the questions raised in the original query. I do not feel the slightest bit of embarrassment, let alone shame or inadequacy, for not having answered a question that was not asked to begin with. If you have a question about something that's not contained in the query above, please feel free to post a *new query*.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to embarrass or shame you in any way. I am sorry if you thought so

Comment: @kksagar - So maybe my choice of words was a bit [!] over the top. My point stands: I'm not bothered by somebody pointing out that I didn't address a question that wasn't asked to begin with.