# Numbering equations with letter and number?

Tags: equations, numbering, labels

I need all the equations in one of the sections to be numbered as letter (R) and an ascending number (1, 2, 3...). So they look like (R1), (R2), (R3) etc.

I do **not** want the number of the section/subsection to appear (not like R3.1.1, R3.1.2, R3.2.1 ...) but just an ascending number starting from the beginning of the section, for all the rest of the sections I am satisfied with LaTeX default numbering.

Numbering these equations manually is not an option because while I am writing my paper I often change the order of the equations or add/remove equations from the text.

Answer (score 11):

```
\section{whatever}
\renewcommand\theequation{R\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but where does it come in the equation? can you please give a more detailed example?

Comment: And how do I refer later to this equation? Thanks.

Comment: @user39532 really _you_ should be supplying the example in the question:-) (all questions should include example code) but anyway the equations are just marked up as normal after you put that at the start of the section eg `\begin{equation}1=1\end{equation}`

Comment: @user39532 your followup questions are unrelated to the main question, the `\label` `\ref` mechanism works however equations are numbered, if you need help with that, please see any latex tutorial or ask a new question.

Comment: @user39532 - For much more information on LaTeX's cross-referencing methods and packages, including some that work with equations, see also the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001).

Comment: Hey, I found this advice very usefull, thanks! However, how do I return to normal (default) labeling at the next chapters?

Comment: I already found a solution, I put the whole section inside a { } so the renew command affects only this section, thanks.