# Reference equation in align* environment with cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, align, cleveref

In order to control equations numbering I use the `Align*` environment where I put `\numberthis` at the end of the equation that I want to number. After, I label the numbered equation but when I want to make a reference to that equation using `\cref` command of the `cleveref` package I obtain a wrong reference (to another page).
It is working with the minimal working example below, but it is not working in my thesis document (the reference send me to a figure in the page before the equation). Could some one say to me if there is something wrong ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} % for numbering in  the align* environment
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{align*}
a & = b \numberthis \label{eqn413} \\
c & = d \\
e & = f \\
\end{align*}
\newpage
The \cref{eqn413} show that bla bla.
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use the `align` (not starred) environment, and put `\notag` on the lines you *don't* want numbered.  that should keep everything in synch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `\refstepcounter{equation}` to get links correctly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\numberthis{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}} % for numbering in  the align* environment
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{align*}
a & = b \numberthis \label{eqn413} \\
c & = d \\
e & = f \\
\end{align*}
\newpage
The \cref{eqn413} show that bla bla.
\end{document}
```

Further, it may be better label like `\label{eq:<some name you will easily remember>}` instead of numbers. `eq` says that it is an equation label and the name is unique to that equation.  Please refer to: [this Q and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152196/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-the-notation-fig-in-the-label/152200#152200).

Comment: It's working good !. For your comment, I'd say it is not possible for me to use the `:` in the label equation. For exemple when I use `label{eq:exemple}` there will be an error message `! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \penalty`. But it is working with `label{eqexemple}` without the `:`.

Comment: @user40953 That was some advertisement on good habits :-) I don't know why it throws an error for you though unless there is some mwe for it ;-). I doubt it on babel.

Comment: You have right :-). I use `babel` in my thesis deocument and when I added `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` to the MWE above I get the error message. Do you suggest a solution for that :-) ?

Comment: What I do in such a case is to use \label{eq-exemple} instead. This is because with frenchb, ‘:’ is an active character, while ‘-’ is not.

Comment: @user40953 That will  be a candidate for a separate new question, I believe. But, if it doesn't affect other things for you, you may put `\shorthandoff{:}` after the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: The @Bernard answer work well. I think I'll avoide the use of `shorthandoff{:}` because I don't know if it it will affect others things.