# How can I cite to figure?

Tags: captions, citing

I use package `caption` and I want to cite to a figure, but I can't cite. How can I cite to figure?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=plain,labelsep=period}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{pic_02}
\label{toan1}
\caption{{}}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
See Figure~\cite{toan1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I got 
[image]

This is a figure.

[image]

Comment: replace `\cite` by `\ref`.

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't get correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example has a few flaws:

1. Use `\ref` instead of `\cite`: [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111280)
2. The `\label` has to be placed after `\caption`: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325)
3. It is advised to use the `fig:<name>` notation for figure labels: [What is the advantage of using the notation 'fig:' in the \label {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152196)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Look at my picture}
  \label{fig:toan1}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{fig:toan1}

\end{document}
```

[image]