# Using \autoref with tcolorbox

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

Is there a way to refer to a *tcolorbox* created theorem (created with `\newtcbtheorem`) using *hyperref*'s `\autoref`?

I've tried to set `\<name>autorefname`, as I would have done it for a theorem created with `\newtheorem`, but it does not seem to work for `\newtcbtheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% tcolorbox theorem
\newtcbtheorem{evidence}{Evidence}{}{ev}
\newcommand{\evidenceautorefname}{Evidence}

% classic theorem
\newtheorem{classicevidence}{Evidence}
\newcommand{\classicevidenceautorefname}{Evidence}

\begin{document}
Find the most important text
in~\autoref{ev:one} % Does not work correctly
and in~\autoref{ev:two}. % Works as expected

\begin{evidence}{This is the evidence}{one}
    Nothing really important to show here.
\end{evidence}

\begin{classicevidence}
    \label{ev:two}
    This is the classic evidence.
\end{classicevidence}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post an entire MWE (minimum working example) that show what you've tried so far. As a minimum, please show the exact code you use when creating a new theorem-like environment via `\newtcbtheorem`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you process your sample document, you get thw warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for
`tcb@cnt@evidence' on input line 18.
```

which shows that `autoref`doesn't recognize the new environment and also shows you the internal name associated to it: `tcb@cnt@evidence` so, internally, your environment's name is not `evidence` but `tcb@cnt@evidence`, which explains why your attempt failed. You need to let `autoref` know about `tcb@cnt@evidence`:

```
\newcommand\tcb@cnt@evidenceautorefname{Evidence}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% tcolorbox theorem
\newtcbtheorem{evidence}{Evidence}{}{ev}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tcb@cnt@evidenceautorefname{Evidence}
\makeatother
% classic theorem
\newtheorem{classicevidence}{Evidence}
\newcommand{\classicevidenceautorefname}{Evidence}

\begin{document}
Find the most important text
in~\autoref{ev:one} % Does not work correctly
and in~\autoref{ev:two}. % Works as expected

\begin{evidence}{This is the evidence}{one}
    Nothing really important to show here.
\end{evidence}

\begin{classicevidence}
    \label{ev:two}
    This is the classic evidence.
\end{classicevidence}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation how to interpret the warning. Works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

The `tcolorbox` package provides some nice hooks to make it cooperate with the `cleveref` package. The solution consists of (a) providing a "label type" when setting up the the theorem and then using a `\crefname` instruction to tell cleveref how to typeset cross-references of that label type. Finally, the command `\cref` of the `cleveref` package can be made to generate cross-references with a look that's identical to that generated by `\autoref` by loading the `cleveref` package with the `nameinlink` option.

For a detailed discussion of various LaTeX cross-referencing packages and macros, including `\autoref` and `\cref`, see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) and the associated answers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% tcolorbox theorem
\newtcbtheorem{evidence}{Evidence}{label type=evidence}{ev}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % make \cref emulate look of \autoref
\crefname{evidence}{Evidence}{Evidence}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Find the most important text in~\cref{ev:one}. % Now works as expected

\begin{evidence}{This is the evidence}{one}
    Nothing really important to show here.
\end{evidence}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a counter of your liking for `\newtcbtheorem`. In the following code, the counter `classicevidence` is taken which would allow a mixed running of both environments.

Alternatively, use `\newcounter{mynicecounter}` and give this counter to `\newtcbtheorem` by `use counter=mynicecounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% classic theorem
\newtheorem{classicevidence}{Evidence}
\newcommand{\classicevidenceautorefname}{Evidence}

% tcolorbox theorem
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=classicevidence]{evidence}{Evidence}{}{ev}

\begin{document}
Find the most important text
in~\autoref{ev:one} % Works as expected
and in~\autoref{ev:two}. % Works as expected

\begin{evidence}{This is the evidence}{one}
    Nothing really important to show here.
\end{evidence}

\begin{classicevidence}
    \label{ev:two}
    This is the classic evidence.
\end{classicevidence}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222434/tcolorbox-autoreference if this doesn't seem to work for you