# Referring to a custom environment with hyperref

Tags: hyperref

I have in my preamble the following code that creates the `boxalign*` environment, which is a boxed `align*` environment.

```latex
\makeatletter  % Code for the boxalign* environment
% \newcommand\boxalign*autorefname{Box}
\@fleqntrue{}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newenvironment{boxalign*}{\@fleqntrue\empheq[box=\fbox]{align*}}{\endempheq}
\@fleqnfalse{}
\makeatother
```

However, I want to refer to this box, but `hyperref` doesn't recognize the environment and therefore doesn't create the hyperlink. For instance:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter  % Code for the boxalign* environment
% \newcommand\boxalign*autorefname{Box}
\@fleqntrue{}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newenvironment{boxalign*}{\@fleqntrue\empheq[box=\fbox]{align*}}{\endempheq}
\@fleqnfalse{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{boxalign*}\label{eq:linear_equation}
    y &= ax + b \\
    \frac{y - b}{a} &= x
\end{boxalign*}

This \hyperref[eq:linear_equation]{hyperref} doesn't work.

\end{document}
```

I saw [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179948/using-autoref-with-tcolorbox) that seemed to have an answer to my problem, which is why I tried adding the `\newcommand\boxalign*autorefname{Box}` line, but it didn't work (so I commented it out).

How can I do this?

Comment: The `align*` environment isn't numbered, I don't know much about the implementation of links within documents or `hyperref` but I'm pretty sure that something like `\refstepcounter` needs to be called for `hyperref` to be able to link to it. Removing the `*` to get `align` makes the link work but then you have a numbered environment which I assume you don't want

Comment: @Willoughby I thought of this but since you can use `\label{}` on standard text (so, unnumbered) I thought it wouldn't be a problem. Anyway, it does work if I use `align`, but as you guessed, I don't want the numbers since I use this boxed environment as an aside in another `align` environment...

Comment: When you use `\label` on 'standard text' it picks up the last time `\refstepcounter` was called, (its actually a bit smarter than this I think, again I don't know much about the implementation of references). This means that it will pick up the section or subsection number for example. If you try to use `\label` without first using something like section you get an error

Comment: the problem is that the environement suppresses the label completly. So hyperref has not real chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cheat the math environment to let the \label command by using another name. You should also set a \phantomsection so that there is a destination for the link:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter  % Code for the boxalign* environment
% \newcommand\boxalign*autorefname{Box}
\@fleqntrue{}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newenvironment{boxalign*}{\@fleqntrue\empheq[box=\fbox]{align*}\phantomsection}{\endempheq}
\@fleqnfalse{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\let\mylabel\label

\begin{boxalign*}\mylabel{eq:linear_equation}
    y &= ax + b \\
    \frac{y - b}{a} &= x
\end{boxalign*}

This \hyperref[eq:linear_equation]{hyperref} doesn't work.

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I add the `\let\mylabel\label` line and change the `\label{}` for `mylabel{}` I get errors on the `\hyperref` line: `Argument of \@fifthoffive has an extra }.` and `Paragraph ended before \@fifthoffive was complete.` Do you know what could cause this? I copied and pasted the code from this answer, and checked that all opening braces had matching closing braces.

Comment: sorry one shouldn't make last minute changes. I thought it would be cleaner if the \let were in the preamble, but this is naturally to early.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Ulrike Fischer's answer is passing the label as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter  % Code for the boxalign* environment
\@fleqntrue
\usepackage{empheq}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxalign*}{o}
 {%
  \@fleqntrue\empheq[box=\fbox]{align*}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\phantomsection}%
 }
 {%
  \endempheq
  \IfValueT{#1}{\label{#1}}%
 }
\@fleqnfalse
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Some text before the alignment
\begin{boxalign*}[eq:linear_equation]
    y &= ax + b \\
    \frac{y - b}{a} &= x
\end{boxalign*}

\newpage

This \hyperref[eq:linear_equation]{hyperref} works.

\end{document}
```