# Cleveref with a same counter used in multiple environments of \newtcbtheorem

Tags: tcolorbox, cleveref

I’m using the \newtcbtheorem in tcolorbox package to produce my environments for theorem, lemma and proposition. I want these three environements be numbered by a same counter, producing a result like

> Theorem 1.1
>
> Proposition 1.2
>
> Lemma 1.3
>
> Theorem 1.4
>
> …

So I write essentially

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=tcb@cnt@theorem, number within=section]{proposition}{Proposition}{}{pr}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=tcb@cnt@theorem, number within=section]{lemma}{Lemma}{}{le}
```

However, when I want to refer these using \cref in cleveref package, I find that if I use \crefname to define the text in \cref, then the code should be like

```
\crefname{counter name of theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{counter name of proposition}{proposition}{propositions}
\crefname{counter name of lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
```

so with these three using a same counter, the last command takes place of the two before it, so whenever I refer to a theorem or proposition by

```
\cref{th:label}
```

the text before the number appears to be ``lemma’’.

Is there any way to fix this, without abandoning the usage of \cref?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need `tcolorbox` option `label type`, see the package manual and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179962.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ It works! Thank you so much.

Comment: Perhaps you can post an answer yourself then accept it, so that the question would be well closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @muzimuzhiZ 's comment, I find that adding a ``label type=name'' in the option fixes this.

Codes:

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{label type=theorem}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=tcb@cnt@theorem, number within=section]{proposition{Proposition}{label type=proposition}{pr}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=tcb@cnt@theorem, number within=section]{lemma} {Lemma}{label type=proposition=lemma}{le}
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{proposition}{proposition}{propositions}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
```