# Cross-references and citation call-outs in color

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I want to know what are the packages that do the following. When I cross-reference an Assumption or Theorem or cite a bibliographic entry ... I want that it will be colored in blue. I will put images to explain more what i mean
[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably `hyperref` with option `colorlinks`. You can choose the color of links via the key `linkcolor=…`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do the following to get all citation call-outs and all cross-references to items (including the names of the items) colored in blue:

- Load the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) package with the options `colorlinks=true` and `allcolors=blue`. This will assure that citation call-outs are colored in blue.
- Load the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/) package with the options `nameinlink`, `noabbrev`, and `capitalize`. (You can omit the latter two options if you're OK with abbreviated and lower-cased item names.)
- Use the macro `\cref` to create cross-references to pages, sections, assumptions, equations, etc.

For (much) more on the subject of creating cross-references (including the `cleveref` package), I suggest reading the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Start} \label{sec:start}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

See \cref{sec:start} and \cref{eq:pyth}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,pagebackref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{{\color{blue}\ref{#1}}}

\section{Hello}
\label{sec:hello}

See Section \ref{sec:hello}.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:albert}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

See~(\ref{eq:albert}).

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Code improved as suggest by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico).

Comment: The OP mentioned wanting all cross-references in blue. I thus wouldn't mention the option `urlcolor=black`. The option `allcolors=blue` may be most appropriate for the OP's stated objective.

Comment: @Mico, with `allcolors=blue` the code do not work.

Comment: Hi, thank you Giacomo, in your example the numbers are colored it is OK but what I want is: when I refer as  Equation~\ref{eq:albert}, I want that the word Equation will be colored also. Thank you

Comment: That's strange -- the combination `colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue` works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Mico I work with MikTeX and Windows but... this do not must is a problem.

Comment: Please check if the code given in my answer (which also uses `allcolors=blue`, on a MacBook running MacTeX2014) compiles on your system. I can see no reason why it shouldn't when run on a Windows system and MikTeX.