# Modified autoref equation name screws up list of figures when a caption includes \autoref{eq}

Tags: hyperref

Consider below MCWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.7}}

\let\orgautoref\autoref
\providecommand{\Autoref}{\def{equationautorefname{Eq.}\orgautoref}
\renewcommand{\autoref}{\def\equationautorefname{eq.}\orgautoref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Bla}
\section{Bla}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{\Autoref{bla} \autoref{bla}\label{fig}}
\end{figure}
\autoref{fig}
\begin{equation}
bla\label{bla}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Bloo}
\section{Bloo}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{Bloo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I comment out the `\autoref` redefinition above, everything works, but if I don't, a second run of pdflatex or latex gives this error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.2 ...quation{eq.}\autoref {bla}}}{1}{figure.1.1}

Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
```

The culprit is the `\listoffigures`, and the error refers to the `.lof` file, which contains the following:

```
\addvspace {10pt}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Bla \def Equation{eq.}\autoref {bla}}}{1}{figure.1.1}
\addvspace {10pt}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2.1}{\ignorespaces Bloo}}{3}{figure.2.1}
```

which seems wrong to me: the `\autorefequationname` ("Equation") has already been expanded instead of the `\def` command being executed.
The documentclass doesn't really matter, it also occurs with e.g. `book`.

How can I solve this error? I have renamed all `\autoref` names and also introduced an `\Autoref`, so I really don't want to stop using it, unless there is no other way.

Comment: @Mico Yeah, that's the point, I need/want that bit (or equivalent).

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. I need that uncommented.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need to wrap the instruction `\def\equationautorefname{eq.}` inside a `\renewcommand` for `\autoref`. Why not just execute it by itself?

Comment: @Mico Right, because then the `\Autoref` command (which was missing from my original example) won't work anymore (see updated code). By writing both like this, it magically works. I understand it's a bit of a hack, but I didn't find any other way of doing this.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I can work around this issue by using `\caption`'s optional argument for a short caption, which is then placed in the list of figures instead. If I avoid `\autoref` there, I should be fine. A better solution is still welcome though!

Comment: I've just posted a solution that uses the cross-referencing powers of the `cleveref` package. Hope it works for you. For (much) more information about the cross-referencing capabilities of the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages see, e.g., the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

Comment: The definition of `\Autoref` is fragile, it contains an assignment, thus `\protect\Autoref` is needed in moving arguments as in `\caption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than hack the `\autoref` macro, I would recommend you load the [cleveref](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package with the option `nameinlink`. That way, all call-outs generated by `\cref` and `\Cref` -- the former for lowercase names, the latter for upper case names -- will appear like the call-outs generated by `\autoref`. In your editing software, do a global change of `\autoref` to `\cref` and of `\Autoref` to `\Cref`, and you'll be all set.

The LoF from your example code would look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.7}}

\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.} % force abbreviated forms for equation "names"
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\mainmatter

\chapter{Bla}
\section{Bla}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{\Cref{bla} \cref{bla} \label{fig}}
\end{figure}
\cref{fig}
\begin{equation}
bla\label{bla}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Bloo}
\section{Bloo}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{Bloo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```