# How to use lowercase "equation" when using \autoref?

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing

When using `\autoref` (not `\eqref` as stated previously), we get the following expression,

```
Equation (#)
```

However, it doesn't make grammatical sense.

For example, it is more natural (in my opinion) to say that:

```
See equation (#)
```

versus

```
See Equation (#)
```

How to set 'Equation' to lowercase 'equation' by default?

Comment: You can set the prefix with `\def\equationautorefname{equation}` directly below `\usepackage{hyperref}` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137435/).

Comment: Some alternate possiblities: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103546/how-do-i-configure-a-ref-of-a-label-to-print-more-than-just-the-number, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5767/how-to-get-more-complete-references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than modifying the `\xxxautorefname` macros by hand, I suggest you load the `cleveref` package (*after* loading `hyperref`) and use `\cref` for lowercase label strings and `\Cref` for uppercase label strings.

A part of your preamble would look like this:

```
...
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
...
```

Next, in the body of the document, perform a global search-and-replace of `\autoref` with `\cref`.

In case you're curious: The `nameinlink` option makes the cross-referencing call-outs produced by `\cref` look like those produced by `\autoref`.

For more on cross-referencing packages for LaTeX in general and the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages in particular, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36312/5001) to the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) (Shameless self-citation alert!)

Comment: For a related posting, see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236325/5001) to the query [Modified \autoref equation name screws up ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236317/5001)