# Why does \ref only enter the numbers?

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there way so that one can replace `By Theorem \ref{theo1}` by `By \ref{theo1}` without changing output in the following  document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{theo1}
I exist.
\end{theorem}


By Theorem \ref{theo1}, I exist.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the cleveref package

Comment: There are many packages that can do this.  See [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36295/cross-reference-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict) for lots of examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [cleveref](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package provides the macro `\cref`, which does what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo1}
I think.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo2}
I think some more.
\end{theorem}

By \cref{theo1}, I exist.

By \cref{theo1,theo2}, I exist some more.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just ve aware if the problems regarding using shared counters