# changing color when lemma or theorem is cross-referenced

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color, theorems

So, using `hyperref` I know how to change the color of "1" to blue when I say "using Theorem 1". But I want the entire "Theorem 1" to be blue. Similarly when I recall a `lemma`/`theorem`/`proposition`/`definition` I want it to be colored in blue including the number that appears after this.

Comment: something like `\newcommand{\refth}[1]{{\color{blue}Theorem \ref{#1}}}` would be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the theorem in question has been defined with a package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` and that it's been given the "label" `thm:abc`.

Two suggestions:

1. Since you're loading the `hyperref` package, you could use the command `\autoref{thm:abc}` to cross-reference the theorem.
2. In addition to loading the `hyperref` package, you could load the `cleveref` package with the option `nameinlink`. With this setup, `\cref{thm:abc}` will also generate a cross-reference call-out in which both the name and the number of the theorem are colored.

For more information on cross-referencing possibilities and packages, see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

Here's an MWE (minimum working example) that uses some of the cross-referencing capabilities of the `cleveref` package. To change the color used in the cross-references from `red` (the default) to `blue`, add the optio `linkcolor=blue` when loading the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}

% set up a few theorem-like environments
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\begin{document}
% define
\begin{thm}\label{thm:abc}    abc \end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{lem:def}    def \end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{prop:ghi}  ghi \end{prop}
\begin{defn}\label{defn:jkl}  jkl \end{defn}

\noindent
\cref{thm:abc}, \cref{lem:def}, \cref{prop:ghi}, \cref{defn:jkl}.

\end{document}
```