# Why, using \ref{fig:customers} to show the label, is the word "Figure" missing?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have a figure to be referenced as below. Why, using `\ref{fig:customers}` to show the label, is the word "Figure" missing? Only the figure number is shown: "3.2". How can I change it to "Figure 3.2"?

```
Potential customers are listed in the `\ref{fig:customers}` below.

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{needs_customers.png}
%[clip=true]
\caption{Potential Customers, Requirement and Constraints}
\label{fig:customers}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A longer discussion of which LaTeX packages provide support for cross-referencing, see [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001). You may be particularly interested in `\autoref` (from the `hyperref` package) and `\cref` (from the `cleveref` package).

Comment: By default the counter type is not shown in the referencing, i.e. `Figure` etc. As Mico mentioned, `cleveref` and `hyperref` provide special commands for this.

Answer (score 5):

There are packages that do that. One of them is `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{An example}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

Please see \autoref{fig:example}.
\end{document}
```

[image: results]

Another option is the `cleveref`-package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{An example}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

Please see \cref{fig:example}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of the references to some certain counter do not provide the name of the counter (say `figure` or `table` etc.).

`hyperref` and `cleveref` amongst other packages provide this missing feature however, there might be other packages as well.

Here I present a solution which is working and quite quick if there should be no other package included (sometimes this is demanded by publishers and their weird settings!)

Without special package: Change the `\p@figure` references formatter macro to use `\figurename`.

The `hyperref` package is used here to show that the redefinition of `\p@figure` still works with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@figure}{\figurename\ }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

You must see the incredible \ref{fig:foo}.

\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Foo caption}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. I never thought of something like that. But this makes it hard to use something where the figure name has to be changed declined.

Comment: @Skillmon: It's quite handy (and sometimes there must be 'dirty' tricks with this `\p@....` macros to allow some special form of referencing.) Of course, for more than just one counter type this might get tedious

Comment: The varioref package also provides a similar service.

Comment: @PeterFlynn: I know, but I don't use that package