# How to control the case of the first letter of a referred title

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref

I am writing a text for raw beginners and I don't want the references to be too much in the way. The issue is best seen from a MWE

[image]

And here is the code

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={alert}{alerts},
Crefname={Alert}{Alerts},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=ALERT \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{ONE}\label{1-0-0}
    \section{One}\label{1-1-0}
    \subsection{one}\label{1-1-1} 
\emph{Relative to the title of the tcolorbox}
\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-2}]{infinity}
    is not a number
\end{greement}
\emph{cref gives}

The \cref{abc:3-2} is most important

\emph{while Cref gives}

\Cref{abc:3-2} is most important

\emph{But I would also like to control the case of the title and, while nameref gives}

We can see \nameref{abc:3-2} 

\emph{Nameref gives}

 \Nameref{abc:3-2} can be seen.

\emph{instead of the desired}

Infinity can be seen.

    \subsection{infinity}\label{1-1-2} 

\emph{Similarly, relative to the title of the subsection, nameref gives}

Since \nameref{1-1-2} is not a number,  ...

\emph{but, I would also like to have it also with an upper case}

Infinity not being a number, ...

\emph{but Nameref does do it}: \Nameref{1-1-2}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Since it did something, I thought there was. But can it be defined so as to let the case of first letter of the title be the opposite of what it is in the title: upper ––> lower and lower ––> upper?

Comment: It is there actually, I forgot about.

Comment: Well, I had a bad typo in the code anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I defined a new macro named `\NameRef` which is different from the `\Nameref` macro provided by `hyperref` -- it uses `\FirstUpcase` which is an `expl3` - defined command that uses uppercase for the first character of the argument only, which is extracted with `\getrefkeybydefault{#1}{name}{-1}`. If the reference does not exist, `-1` is typeset.

The starred version `\NameRef*` will not add a hyperlink.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_tail:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_uppercase:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn {Nx,No}
\newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]{%
  \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str {#1}%
  \str_uppercase:x {\str_head:N \l_tmpa_str}\str_tail:V {\l_tmpa_str}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
    \NewDocumentCommand{\NameRef}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}%
  }{%
    \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#2}{}{%
      % label is defined, now get hyperlink
      \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{anchor}{-1}}{\FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}}
    }%
  }%
}

\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={alert}{alerts},
Crefname={Alert}{Alerts},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=ALERT \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}\label{1-0-0}
\section{One}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{one}\label{1-1-1} 
\emph{Relative to the title of the tcolorbox}
\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-2}]{infinity}
  is not a number
\end{greement}
\emph{cref gives}

The \cref{abc:3-2} is most important

\emph{while Cref gives}

\Cref{abc:3-2} is most important

\emph{But I would also like to control the case of the title and, while nameref gives}

We can see \nameref{abc:3-2} 

\emph{Nameref gives}

 \Nameref{abc:3-2} can be seen.

\emph{instead of the desired}

Infinity can be seen.

\subsection{infinity}\label{1-1-2} 

\emph{Similarly, relative to the title of the subsection, nameref gives}

Since \nameref{1-1-2} is not a number,  ...

\emph{but, I would also like to have it also with an upper case}

Infinity not being a number, ...

\emph{but Nameref does not work at all}: \NameRef{1-1-2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** A version without `expl3`, using 'usual' `TeX` only for `\FirstUpcase`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\def\first@up#1#2\relax{%
  \uppercase{#1}#2%
}

\newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\first@up#1\relax%
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\NameRef}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}%
  }{%
    \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#2}{}{%
      % label is defined, now get hyperlink
      \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{anchor}{-1}}{\FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}}
    }%
  }%
}


\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={alert}{alerts},
Crefname={Alert}{Alerts},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=ALERT \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}\label{1-0-0}
\section{One}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{one}\label{1-1-1} 
\emph{Relative to the title of the tcolorbox}
\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-2}]{infinity}
  is not a number
\end{greement}
\emph{cref gives}

The \cref{abc:3-2} is most important

\emph{while Cref gives}

\Cref{abc:3-2} is most important

\emph{But I would also like to control the case of the title and, while nameref gives}

We can see \nameref{abc:3-2} 

\emph{Nameref gives}

 \Nameref{abc:3-2} can be seen.

\emph{instead of the desired}

Infinity can be seen.

\subsection{infinity}\label{1-1-2} 

\emph{Similarly, relative to the title of the subsection, nameref gives}

Since \nameref{1-1-2} is not a number,  ...

\emph{but, I would also like to have it also with an upper case}

Infinity not being a number, ...

\emph{NameRef works here}: \NameRef{1-1-2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I will update with the hyperlink facility

Comment: Doesn't work here: "./NameRefHupfer2.tex:13: LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \str_upper_case:n undefined.
"

Comment: @schremmer: Again an outdated TeX distribution, I assume

Comment: @Well, the typeset above doesn't show it: it still has `on page 1` and it looks to be the one I had before I replaced "does not work at all" by "does not do it". But I will check the dates on the packages.

Comment: @schremmer: There is an upper case `Infinity`, isn't it? That's what you wanted, if I understood your question correctly

Comment: @schremmer: I provided a non `expl3` version

Comment: 1. You understood my question perfectly. It is my eyes that are OLD. 2. Your version "without exp13" works fine. 3. You cannot imagine the relief not having to upgrade. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: I don't think that `\str_upper_case:nx` is the right approach; the `\tl_` module should be used.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just tried it in the magnum opus and it still worked. But there I noticed that, while NameRef does `lower ––> upper` it also does `upper ––> upper` instead of `upper ––> lower`which would be very nice.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Or, for `upper ––> lower`, maybe just another macro, nameRef?