# How to completely control the case of the first letter of a referred title

Tags: cleveref, capitalization

In [How to control the case of the first letter of a referred title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392567/how-to-control-the-case-of-the-first-letter-of-a-referred-title), I somehow ended up asking for a macro that would change the initial letter from `lower case` to `upper case`and with his `\NameRef`, Christian Hupfer did just that.

But, going back to the magnum opus, I was quickly reminded that I also needed a macro that would change the initial letter from `upper case` to `lower case`. So, could Hupfer's `\NameRef` be modified to make either change depending on whether the initial letter is `lower case` or `upper case`?

His code is in:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\def\first@up#1#2\relax{%
  \uppercase{#1}#2%
}

\newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\first@up#1\relax%
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\NameRef}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}%
  }{%
    \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#2}{}{%
      % label is defined, now get hyperlink
      \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{anchor}{-1}}{\FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}}
    }
  }%
}

\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={alert}{alerts},
Crefname={Alert}{Alerts},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=ALERT \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}\label{1-0-0}
\section{One}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{one}\label{1-1-1} 
\emph{Relative to the title of the tcolorbox}
\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-1}]{infinity}
  is not a number
\end{greement}
\emph{nameref  gives}

We can see \nameref{abc:3-1} 

\emph{Hupfer's NameRef gives}

 \NameRef{abc:3-1} can be seen.

\emph{Similarly, relative to the title of the subsection, nameref gives}

Since \nameref{1-1-1} is a number,  ...

\emph{and Hupfer's NameRef gives}

\NameRef{1-1-1} being a number


\textbf{all of which is what I asked for.} 
\subsection{Two}\label{1-1-2}
But with
\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-2}]{Infinity}
  is not everything
\end{greement}

\emph{I would like }

``We can see that infinity is not everything''

but \emph{nameref  gives} 

We can see that \nameref{abc:3-2} is not everything

and

\emph{NameRef also gives}

We can see that \NameRef{abc:3-2} is not everything.


\emph{Similarly, relative to the title of the subsection, nameref gives}

\nameref{1-1-2} is a number

but I would also like

Since two is a number

while, at this time, Hupfer's NameRef gives

Since \NameRef{1-1-2} is a number

\end{document}
```

and here is what the code gives:

[image]

Comment: The problem is to determine whether the usage of such a reference command is at the beginning of a sentence etc. This is not easy, in my point of view and it is easier to take care of the correct form yourself than let TeX etc. do it for you

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did not make myself clear: What I really need is a macro that just does the symmetric of NameRef, the one you made, that is I need a macro that changes `upper case` into `lower case` just the way your NameRef changed `lower case` into `upper case`. But I thought that the two could then be combined into one with an `either/or`. However that would be "icing on the cake" and if I had two macros I certainly could decide which one to use depending on the place in the sentence.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I made a copy of NameRef, changed up to low, etc AND IT WORKED. So, I am happy. Of course, I could not bring myself to try to join them with an `either/or.

Comment: sigh... of course another definition of something like `\nameRef` etc with `\lowercase` would have been very easy -- if I would have known that you meant that one ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I needed BOTH and they work just as they should. Just one thing: when they do not find the label, they do not show anything instead of showing `??`. At times, it makes editing a bit unnerving. So, if you could fix that, I would be most grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by not finding the label?

Comment: Suppose I have `\Cref{abc:3-2}` but that I made a mistake and there is no `\label{abc:3-2}`. Then, the pdf will show `??` but with `\NameRef{abc:3-2}` the pdf will not show anything. Not a big deal. Just that, as I said, it makes editing a bit harder.

Comment: What do you think ` \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#2}{}{...}` does in the code? It checks for the existence of a reference. Just fill in `??` or whatever you like in the empty `{}` pair ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I apologize but since I do not understand `LaTeX` I am not about to make the slightest change to your code. I just copy-paste it. And, indeed, now that I typed in `??` in the blank, it works. Which, as I keep moving stuff around and thereby breaking references, makes my editing quite a bit easier.

Comment: I think the issue is solved then...