# How to change case of first letter in a reference

Tags: macros, cleveref, xparse

[How to completely control the case of the first letter of a referred title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393442/how-to-completely-control-the-case-of-the-first-letter-of-a-referred-title) does exactly that but it seems to me that one command should do it

```
*emphasized text*\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
    \def\first@up#1#2\relax{\uppercase{#1}#2}%
    \newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]%
        {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\first@up#1\relax}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \def\first@low#1#2\relax{\lowercase{#1}#2}%
    \newcommand{\FirstLowcase}[1]%
        {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\first@low#1\relax}%
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand%
    {\TitleRef}{sm}%
    {%begin definition
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
            {%
                \FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}%
             }% 
            {%
                \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#2}{}% 
                    {% begin label is defined, now get hyperlink
                        \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{anchor}{-1}}%creates the link
                        {\FirstUpcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}}%error otherwise
                }% end label is defined, now get hyperlink
            }%
    }%end definition

\NewDocumentCommand%
    {\titleRef}{sm}%
    {%begin definition
          \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
              {%
                \FirstLowcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}%
              }% 
              {%
                \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#2}{}%
                    {% begin label is defined, now get hyperlink
                        \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{anchor}{-1}}%
                        {\FirstLowcase{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{-1}}}%
                     }% end label is defined, now get hyperlink
            }% end if false
    }%definition

\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]%
{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    {\color{#1}%
    \fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{ONE}\label{1}
\section{lower}\label{1-1}
\section{Upper}\label{1-2}

Here are what the two commands I have, courtesy of Christian Hufner, do:

TitleRef on lower: \hspace{5mm}  \TitleRef{1-1}\hspace{5mm} (lower changed to Lower)

TitleRef on Upper: \hspace{5mm}  \TitleRef{1-2}\hspace{5mm} (Not changed)

titleRef on Upper: \hspace{5mm}  \titleRef{1-2}\hspace{5mm} (Upper changed to upper)

titleRef on lower: \hspace{5mm}  \titleRef{1-1}\hspace{5mm} (Not changed)


\hspace{-6mm}Here is what I would like one command, TtitleRef, to do:

TtitleRef on Upper:  \hspace{5mm}  \cfbox{red}{upper}\hspace{5mm} (Upper changed to upper)

TtitleRef on lower:\hspace{5mm}   \cfbox{red}{Lower}\hspace{5mm} (lower changed to Lower)

\end{document}
```

Here is the pdf:

[image]

Comment: 1. I apologize for butchering your name. Shouldn't have relied on my memory. 2. As far as I can remember---which I just proved isn't far, you did only one the two. (And I did the other by symmetry: in one of my comments there, I wrote: " I made a copy of NameRef, changed up to low, etc AND IT WORKED. So, I am happy. Of course, I could not bring myself to try to join them with an `either/or`). Well, eventually, I did spend several hours trying to do just that and  getting nowhere. So I posted the question

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious to do the uppercase from the lowercase version -- I wrote that already to the other question.

Comment: I agree---and they are both in the MWE above, but that is NOT what I am asking here and that I can't do. Look at the last three lines of the pdf above.

Comment: I have now spent another several hours getting nowhere and, being over eighty one (81) years old, I don't have all the time in the world. So, PLEASE, I want to spend whatever time I have left on a book that could be useful for others, not on learning xparse.

Comment: You demand a command that automatically changes the first letter of a reference to lower case if it is upper case and vice versa -- I told you once that TeX is bad in detecting the case of a letter. It's no wonder there's no `\iflowercase` etc. macro in TeX etc. like it exist in a programming language like `C` (called islower(), if remember correctly). It might be possible with LuaLaTeX, but I don't know anything about Lua

Comment: I really do not understand. How then does your macro work?: In the MWE above, the title of `1-1` is "lower" and the output of `\TitleRef{1-1}` is "Lower" which is the opposite while the title of `1-2` is "Upper" and the output of `\TitleRef{1-2}` is "Upper" which is NOT the opposite. So, why can't the output be the opposite here too? Which would be what I want.

Comment: `\TitleRef` uses `\FirstUpcase`, which will return the first letter upcase, regardless which case it has, so 'a' will be turned to 'A', but 'A' will remain 'A'. As far as I know TeX does not provide a `\togglecase` macro which is what you desire

Comment: Now I understand. What threw me off was the `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{}` which gave me the impression that there was a conditional somewhere around. (I still don't get it.) Sorry about that but you vastly overrated my LaTeX competency. But, thanks again for the single commands. I will live.

Comment: The `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{}` just tests for the starred version of `\TitleRef` which would then not generate a hyperlink, such as `\ref*` or `\nameref*` display the reference value but generate no hyperlink

Comment: I was indeed wondering about the stars. But this goes to show that one can learn at any age. By the way, it turns out that the single commands---as opposed to the  compound command that cannot be---are really nice because this way, for a change, I know what I am doing. Well, sorry for this tempest in a teapot. Thanks again for your patience.