# Easy way to cross-reference many equations

Tags: cross-referencing

I got a document with many (over 100) equations, in which I think during the work on it I'll have to change, switch, remove them etc. I often want to refer to an equation but due to the work in progress it's not really convenient to `\label` every equation e.g. with a number and `\ref` to it. Is there an easier way to do this with some auto labeling and a straight forward refer even if I change order etc.

Comment: This is what LaTeX's `\label` `\ref` mechanism is for.

Comment: So best is just to find a logical way to \label all my equations

Comment: Logical, meaning I think, mnemonic.  It serves no use (and may actually throw confusion) to say `\begin{equation}E=mc^2\label{eq:1}\end{equation}`, but rather one should say something like `\begin{equation}E=mc^2\label{eq:einstein}\end{equation}`.  And you don't have to `\label` all the equations...only the ones you reference.  Bottom line is that automatic labeling is meaningless labeling.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

If you're `\label`ing the equations numerically in ascending order, you're not using the tool appropriately. The arguments of `\label` should indicate, in some abbreviated and hopefully recognizable way, *what* it being cross-referenced. E.g., one might write

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:einstein_energy}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
```

With this setup, no matter if the equation is ends up being numbered `1`, `55`, or any other number, you can cross-reference from anywhere in the document by writing

```
\ref{eq:einstein_energy}
```

You certainly won't have to change the argument of `\label` (and `\ref`) simply because the number assigned to the equation has changed.

If you need to cross-reference *ranges* of equations, you should look into loading the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/) package and using its `\crefrange` macro, as is demonstrated in the following example. Note that the middle three equations aren't even assigned `\label`s.

For more information on cross-referencing mechanisms and packages, please the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % for "\crefrange" macro
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:one_one}  1+1=2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}                    2+2=4 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}                    3+3=6 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}                    4+4=8 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:zero_zero}0+0=0 \end{equation}
A cross-reference to \crefrange{eq:one_one}{eq:zero_zero}.
\end{document}
```