# Can I refer to specific align line numeration, in similar way how I can refer to \bibitem with \cite?

Tags: cross-referencing, align, enumerate, labels

If I make bibliography, then I can make unique name for any position, for example by `\bibitem{tutor}`, then refer to it in the text with `\cite{tutor}`.

---

Now, let's say that I am writing some bigger text, usually using `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` for adding mathematical formulas, so I can format them nicely and have them being automatically enumerated.

While I keep adding and changing things, numeration keeps changing, so something that was previously "Theorem (5.24)" becomes "Theorem (5.36)", etc. It's really problematic, as I have to keep changing it manually, which is inane and adds much of unnecessary work.

Can I make this more flexible, so later I don't have to go through every single reference that I wrote manually and change it to something else?

Maybe there's a way to possibly "label" certain `align` lines and refer to them later, using this unique label in similar way to how I can use `\bibitem` and `\cite`?

Comment: You should definitely familiarize yourself with LaTeX's `\label` and `\ref` macros; the former serves to set a "label" (usually associated with a counter such as `equation` or `theorem`), the latter serves to generate the cross-reference to an object that was labeled elsewhere in the document. Did you see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) The answers discuss both the basic `\label`-`\ref` mechanism as well as various packages which make sophisticated cross-referencing quite straightforward and easy to use.

Comment: @Mico Thank you! I looked into your link, then knowing what to look for I also found the link below, and it looks like `\label{eq:name_here}` and `\ref{name_here}` works for me :-)  
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing

Comment: regarding documentation for `align`. the user guide for `amsmath` may be more reliable than the latex wikibook, which does not always document "best practices".  specifically, `\eqref{...}` is recommended over `\ref{...}` for references to display math.

Comment: it's also worth noting that the `\label` - `\ref` mechanism is also available for theorems.  see the `amsthm` user guide for guidance on using that package.  (other theorem packages provide equivalent facilities.)

Comment: Note that your approach to bibliographies isn't the most efficient one, either. However, perhaps that's something better returned to later.