# Equation autolabelling

Tags: equations

I am just wondering if there is a way to refer to autolabelled equations in the text.

I can use:

```
\begin{equation}
x^2
\end{equation}
```

The equation will autonumber, but I can't refer to it in the text without providing a label, and I don't want to do that because I might be added other equations before it in the future (plus I'd still have to update the text).

Apologies if this has been asked. I have tried to search for it with no luck. Maybe I am using the wrong search terms.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) for an overview and discussion of LaTeX packages that simplify and/or extend cross-referencing to various objects in a document, including equations.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Phelype Oleinik. I made the code bits code but it didn't look right for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to *number* the equations by yourself. Let LaTeX do the heavy lifting. You can just give names to the equations and refer to them by their names:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Equation~\ref{xsquared} shows that the universe is
infinite, but equation~\ref{ysquared} says otherwise.
\begin{equation}\label{xsquared}
  a = x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{ysquared}
  b = y^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you insert an equation before it, LaTeX will do the numbering by itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Equation~\ref{answer} is the Answer to Life, the Universe and Everything

Equation~\ref{xsquared} shows that the universe is
infinite, but equation~\ref{ysquared} says otherwise.
\begin{equation}\label{answer}
  x = y = 42
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{xsquared}
  a = x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{ysquared}
  b = y^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

## Getting fancy :)

Barbara Beeton pointed a few problems with my previous answer.

An empty line between an `\end{equation}` and the next `\begin{equation}` will create an extra empty space between the equations, so I removed them.

Notice also the ugly spacing between equations (1) and (2) in the previous figure. The `gather` environment from `amsmath` allows multiple equations inside the same environment and makes the spacing between them correct. At the same time, it allows one label per equation the same way that the three `equation` environments allowed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Equation~\ref{answer} is the Answer to Life, the Universe and Everything

Equation~\ref{xsquared} shows that the universe is
infinite, but equation~\ref{ysquared} says otherwise.
\begin{gather}
  x = y = 42\label{answer}\\
  a = x^2\label{xsquared}\\
  b = y^2\label{ysquared}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Much better now :)

Comment: there's an awful lot of space above and between these equations.  it's not recommended to leave a blank line above any display, and if multiple equations are grouped with no (or very little) text between them, using a multi-line structure from `amsmath` is also recommended.  (`gather` would be the most appropriate here.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I didn't notice that a blank line above a math display would create those spaces. Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: Thanks Phelype Oleinik, I guess I was just putting the label in the wrong place