# I want a good explanation of how to use \ref , \tag , \label when dealing with texts and equations and mathematical proofs?

Tags: labels, ref, tag

I don't have experience with how to deal with `\ref`, `\tag` and `\label`, and how they work together and on their own.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Cross_referencing_sections_and_equations

Comment: the general use of label and ref will be covered by any latex tutorial, the question/answer format of this site works best if you have specific question. If you try a small document that uses `\label` and `\ref` and it doesn't work as you expect, add it to your question and ask about the error that you get.

Comment: If you want to see what is really going on, look at the aux file.

Comment: Of the three macros mentioned by name in the title of your query, `\tag` is completely separate from and independent of `\label` and `\ref`. See also [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001), and especially [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36312/5001), which discusses the basic `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism along with various cross-referencing packages.