# prettyref bug when used with babel-french

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, french, ref

I'm writting in French so I use `babel`. I'd like to use `prettyref` to keep from writting "Section" and co.

**The problem is that I can not use it with French `babel`**. It throws me:

```
! Paragraph ended before \@prettyref was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.36 

?
```

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{prettyref}

% Form package, just for info.
\makeatletter
\def\prettyref#1{\@prettyref#1:}
\def\@prettyref#1:#2:{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pr@#1\endcsname\relax%
    \PackageWarning{prettyref}{Reference format #1\space undefined}%
    \ref{#1:#2}%
    \else%
    \csname pr@#1\endcsname{#1:#2}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

See \prettyref{fig:defs}

\section{Definitions}\label{sec:defs}

See \prettyref{sec:conclusion}

\section{Conclusion}\label{sec:conclusion}

See \prettyref{sec:intro} and \prettyref{fig:defs}. With prettyref we simply write \verb|\prettyref{sec:intro}| to get \prettyref{sec:intro}.

\end{document}
```

## Conclusion

Ok ! For all French peaple looking here, you can't define labels like `fig:a`. This causes problems as soon as an automatic reference package is used.

The reason is that the `:` "letter" becomes an active character in French `babel`, which leads all these problems :s

What I made is to use `cleveref` with labels like `fig-a`.

Thanks everyone !

Comment: `prettyref` is simply not compatible with `babel-french`.

Comment: What egregs says, it is probably because of the active `:`

Comment: @Mico IIRC, current LaTeX kernel copes with `:` in labels, even under `babel-french`.  I recommend against using `:`  with this setup though, precisely because of packages like `cleveref` that don't like it when active.

Comment: @etienne-monier You might want to try [xcref](https://github.com/frougon/xcref), but be warned that it is very experimental, and will quite possibly never be uploaded to CTAN. In particular, the default values may be changed, and the approach used (using `cleveref` as a backend) is a rather brute force one—I don't like it much. And the `cleveref` code takes a *lot* of volume (`\expandafter` chains...). In order to maintain `xcref` long-term, I'd need to be comfortable with the `cleveref` code, but I don't read it often enough for this.

Comment: It's not just `prettyref` that conflicts with `babel-french` and its decision to make the `:` character "active" (in the TeX-sense of the word). Another afflicted cross-referencing package is `cleveref`. Basically, all cross-referencing packages which inspect the contents of `\label` and `\ref` more than just cursorily will experience problems with the active `:` character. In the case of `prettyref`, the problem is unavoidable because the presence of the `:` character is required -- as the divider between the format and name parts of the cross-reference.

Comment: @frougon - Many thanks for pointing out this issue. I've deleted the old comment and added a new one.

Comment: You should probably post that cleveref  question as a separate question as it will never be found by others under the current title (which you should not edit as it suits the original question). Besides the cleveref manual explicitly mentions that it is not compatible with active chars.

Comment: I added an example with varioref and cleveref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `prettyref` compatible with `babel-french` (but the fix will only work with it).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{prettyref}

% fix \prettyref to first detokenize its argument
% kudos to daleif for proposing the simplification
\makeatletter
\def\prettyref#1{\expandafter\@prettyref\detokenize{#1:}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

See \prettyref{fig:defs}

\section{Definitions}\label{sec:defs}

See \prettyref{sec:conclusion}

\section{Conclusion}\label{sec:conclusion}

See \prettyref{sec:intro} and \prettyref{fig:defs}. With prettyref we 
simply write \verb|\prettyref{sec:intro}| to get \prettyref{sec:intro}.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{caption}\label{fig:defs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, a combination of `varioref` and `cleveref` would be more robust. However, `cleveref` doesn't like active colons, but doesn't rely on a precise label naming scheme, so you can use any other separator (avoid French special punctuation, though). The advantage over `prettyref` is that you can decide whether to use `\ref` (just the number), `\cref` (with the type) or `\vref` (with type and reference to the page).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{varioref,cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{Figure}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec-intro}

See \vref{fig-defs}

\section{Definitions}\label{sec-defs}

See \cref{sec-conclusion}

\section{Conclusion}\label{sec-conclusion}

See \cref{sec-intro} and \cref{fig-defs}. With cleveref we 
simply write \verb|\vref{sec-intro}| to get \vref{sec-intro}.

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{caption}\label{fig-defs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have my own personal unreleased reimplementation of fancyref, which also uses `:` as the separator. AFAIR I detokenize the label and that seems to work fine with french babel. Not sure if that helps here.

Comment: @daleif Seems to work, thanks.