# How to handle colon in macro when using babel for french?

Tags: graphics, babel, windows, includegraphics, french

I've recently encountered a problem when trying to combine

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

and

```
\graphicspath{{c:/Users/...}}
```

A problem then appears when I try to use `\includegraphics` (although it perfectly works when french is not selected in babel.)
It appears that babel (with french preset) modify the behavior of the colon (as a spacing is required before it in French).
This problem has already been mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527909/prettyref-bug-when-used-with-babel-french) and some people propose to avoid the use of the colon. In case of a windows Path, its not possible.

For the moment, I've found a simple hack :

```
\usepackage[english,main=french]{babel}
```

and turn to English before including graphics and then return to French.
This solution works utbut is not easy to use as I'm maintaining a repository of various tex files (>1000) used by various users and I can't make them use this trick each time.

Any idea about a better solution ?

Comment: if you use \graphicspath in the preamble it should not be a problem, the colon is not active there yet. But as you didn't show a complete example, it is difficult to say what you are actually doing.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know. 
I did not put a MWE as I also encountered the problem with the import macro, which cannot be used in the preamble.

Comment: This question is clear enough and shouldn't have been closed. Ulrike's @UlrikeFischer comment could be made into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can load `babel` with the `shorthands=` option, for example,

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[main=french, shorthands=off]{babel}
```

You can instead whitelist specific shorthands, instead of turning them `off`, if you need some other shorthands.  The syntax for this is in the `babel` manual.

You could also turn off shorthands temporarily, without switching languages, with `\languageshorthands{none}`.  When you need them again, you can restore `\languageshorthands{french}`.  If you need to wrap an `\originalmacro`, you might try something like:

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{%
  \languageshorthands{none}%
  \originalmacro{#1}%
  \languageshorthands{\languagename}}
```

You could alternatively set the `\catcode` of `:` and other characters that are breaking your commands to 12 within a `\begingroup`, to make them inactive:

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{%
  \begingroup%
    \catcode`:=12%
    \originalmacro{#1}%
  \endgroup}
```

Finally, some packages have their own options to disable shortands inside commands they need to parse, such as the `babel` library of TikZ, which makes the TikZ parser Babel-shorthand-compatible.

Comment: This sound simpler than switching from one to another language but still need to be done before and after each call to macro which use windows paths.

Comment: @M.Miguel-Brebion You could write your own wrapper for those macros. Does `\languageshorthands{none}\originalmacro\languageshorthands{\languagename}` work?

Comment: @M.Miguel-Brebion Posted some examples. (Warning: untested.)

Comment: At least your second example will not work because the colon will already be tokenized with a fixed catcode. I'm fairly sure that the first won't work for the same reason, too.

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is that there are contexts in LaTeX that are essentially "moving" which the `\protect`ion mechanism does not handle. These include file names.

Rather than disabling language shorthands (if, indeed, you do want shorthands), I suggest manually  applying the proper protection:

```
\graphicspath{{C\string:/Users/myself/Pictures}}
```

(Don't use the standard `\protect` but `\string` instead.)