# Fine tuning the cross-reference to a subfigure

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I have a very small (probably silly) issue with reference to a subfigure. I am using the following code snippet for the name and reference to a subfigure:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \thefigure.(\alph{subfigure}):}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
\makeatother
```

Here `\ref` command to a subfigure `\label` is showing the following output:

> `Figure <figure no.>.<(subfigure no.)>:`

How to get rid of the punctuation ' : ' in the reference but keep that in the caption label? Please help.

> MWE:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{mathtools}
> \usepackage{tikz, pgf}
> \usepackage{caption}
> \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
> \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \thefigure.(\alph{subfigure}):}
> \makeatletter
> \renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
> \makeatother
> \begin{document}
>     \begin{figure}[h]
>         \centering
>         \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
>             \centering
>             \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=1.5;b=1;}]
>                 \fill [fill=gray!25] (b,0) node[anchor=south west] {\scriptsize$ (1,0) $} -- (0,b) node[left] {\scriptsize $ (0,1) $} -- (-b,0) node[anchor=north east] {\scriptsize$ (-1,0) $} -- (0,-b) node[right] {\scriptsize$ (0,-1) $} -- cycle;
>                 \draw [<->] (-a,0) -- (a,0);
>                 \draw [<->] (0,-a) -- (0,a);
>                 \draw (0,0) node[above=0.01pt] {\scriptsize$ (0,0) $} circle (1pt);
>             \end{tikzpicture}
>             \caption{$ B_{1}((0,0);1) $}
>         \end{subfigure}
>         \unskip\ \vrule\ 
>         \hfil
>         \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
>             \centering
>             \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=1.5;b=1;}]
>                 \fill [fill=gray!25] (0,0) node[above=0.01pt] {\scriptsize$ (0,0) $} circle (b);
>                 \draw [<->] (-a,0) -- (a,0);
>                 \draw [<->] (0,-a) -- (0,a);
>                 \draw (b,0) node[anchor=south west] {\scriptsize$ (1,0) $};
>                 \draw (0,0) node[above=0.01pt] {\scriptsize$ (0,0) $} circle (1pt);
>             \end{tikzpicture}
>             \caption{$ B_{2}((0,0);1) $}
>             \label{Fig: open ball in p=2}
>         \end{subfigure}
>         \caption{Open unit balls in plane for $ p=1,2,10,\infty $.}
>         \label{Fig: p-open balls}
>     \end{figure}
>     \ref{Fig: open ball in p=2}
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})}`?
Please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I tried this. But then there is no punctuation in the `subfigure` caption label. Let me prepare an MWE.

Comment: Have you tried \subref (page 10).

Comment: @JohnKormylo, it is producing exactly the same thing as `\ref`.

Comment: With `\captionsetup{subrefformat=<name>}` you can format `\subref` separately from `\thesubfigure` or `\ref`.  With `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` (page 24 of caption manual) you can create new format names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked,

> How to get rid of the punctuation `:` in the reference but keep [it] in the caption label?

I think you should change

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \thefigure.(\alph{subfigure}):}
```

to

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})}
```

Put differently, you should move the place where the label separator (`:`) is generated away from where the appearance of the subfigure's number is determined and towards where the appearance of the full caption is determined.

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question, "Can you please tell me how to produce only `\thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})` as the [cross-reference to] a `subfigure`?" (with further updates)

The answer comes in two parts. *First*, change

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})}
```

from the preceding answer to

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{SubhajitPaul}{Figure \bothIfFirst{#1}{\nobreakspace}#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=PaulSubhajitPaul,labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})}
```

i.e., get rid of the "Figure" substring in the definition of `\thesubfigure`, while taking care that "Figure" continues to show up in the caption's label.

*Second*, start using the `cleveref` package and its `\cref` macro to create a cross-referencing call-outs that automatically include the object type -- here: "Figure". One of the many nifty things about `\cref` is that it can take several arguments, and it will determine automatically if the prefix string needs to be rendered in singular or plural. See below for an application.

For more information on cross-referencing packages and an introduction to the `cleveref` package, please see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) (Shameless self-citation alert!)

Finally, a full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

A quick comment: I think that adding the prefix "Figure " to each subfigure's caption number looks heavy-handed and inelegant. Are you really concerned that your readers won't be able to figure out on their own that "(a)" and "(b)" are the numbers associated with two subfigures? I would hope that your readers aren't that dim.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{SubhajitPaul}{Figure \bothIfFirst{#1}{\nobreakspace}#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=SubhajitPaul,labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} % be sure to load 'cleveref' AFTER 'hyperref'
\crefname{subfigure}{Figure}{Figures}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
   \caption{$B_{1}((0,0);1)$} \label{Fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
   \caption{$B_{2}((0,0);1)$} \label{Fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Open unit balls in plane for $ p=1,2,10,\infty $.}
\end{figure}

\cref{Fig:1b}; \cref{Fig:1a,Fig:1b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Another small request. Since I hyperlink the references, I do not want to have the word `Figure` to be hyperlinked while calling the `\ref` for a subfigure. Can you please tell me how to produce only `\thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})`  as the `\ref` for a subfigure?

Comment: I'll post an addendum to address your follow-up question.

Comment: Thank you for your addendum. I did not realise my _request_ was not small and a +1 for _(Shameless self-citation alert!)_! I have two concerns over here. First, the string 'Figure' is not appearing in the subfigure caption label. How to make it appear there? And second, when I modify my `\ref` command to `\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\cref{#1} in \cpageref{#1}}`, and adding `\ref{Fig:1a}`  in your code, it is showing neither the string 'Figure' nor the page number.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul - I've updated the addendum to my answer some more. I couldn't help but insert a remark that implementing your requests ends up creating a heavy-handed, cluttered, and inelegant look. IMNSHO, having three instances of `Figure 1` in close proximity is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, I consider your comment with sincerity and let me decide whether that looks elegant in the context of my book. But to be honest I am more concerned about the second one. I need to have the page number accompanying the `\ref` output. Please help with that.

Comment: I suggest you load the `varioref` package (right before loading `hyperref`) and use the package's `\vref` macro to create cross-references that automatically include a call-out to the page the object is located on if the call-out and the object are placed on different pages. E.g., `\vref{Fig:1b}`.

Comment: Ah! This is great! Thanks.