# Convention on referncing multiple equations in a sentence

Tags: cross-referencing

This is more of a question about convention rather than a specific question about coding in LaTeX. When referencing multiple equations in quick succession, what is the correct convention?

- We can see from Eq. `\ref{EQ:1}` and Eq. `\ref{EQ:2}` that...
- We can see from Eq. `\ref{EQ:1}` and `\ref{EQ:2}` that...
- We can see from Eqs. `\ref{EQ:1}` and `\ref{EQ:2}` that...
- We can see from Eqs. `\ref{EQ:1,EQ:2}` that...

Is there any specific or best practice convention?

Comment: Many people have many different conventions. However, once you have found yours, I recommend using `cleveref`, in particular section **8.2.2 Reference Ranges** of its manual. Please note also that `subequations` can be used to collectively refer to some set of equations.

Comment: (1) and (3) can both be correct, i.e., idiomatic. What's appropriate in a given sentence really depends on what information you're aiming to convey. (2) isn't idiomatic -- at least, not idiomatic English. (4) results in a LateX syntax error.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the suggestion of `cleverref`. Despite using LaTeX for quite a while I had never come across that!

Comment: @Q.P. - See the posting 'Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) and the associated answers for information on packages, including `cleveref`, that simplify the task of creating cross-references.

Comment: @Mico thanks for this! Your point about idiomatic English was a concern of mine as repetitive use of "equation" seems clunky to my ear.

Comment: If you are using `amsmath`, I'd be inclined to recommend "Eqs.~\eqref{EQ:1} and~\eqref{EQ:2}`, or even without the "Eqs.", since the parenthesized references clearly identify these as equations.  (That would be the recommended AMS style, with which I've worked for many years.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the input! Eqs seems idiomatic, as obviously the plural is correct.