# eqref - showonlyrefs

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref, mathtools, ref

I have equations and I want to reference some of them. Also, I would like to number only the equations that I reference. For some reason when I use `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}` - nothing works and when I use `\eqref` it just references the section and not the equation. If I delete `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}`, then all equations are being numbered no matter if I reference them or not.

For example, with the line `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}`:

```
\documentclass[peerreview]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} % Use the [cmex10] option to ensure complicance
                             % with IEEE Xplore (see bare_conf.tex)
\usepackage{subcaption}
%% Please note that the amsthm package must not be loaded with
%% IEEEtran.cls because IEEEtran provides its own versions of
%% theorems. Also note that IEEEXplore does not accepts submissions
%% with hyperlinks, i.e., hyperref cannot be used.
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath }
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500 % As explained in bare_conf.tex 

%%%%%%
% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.48} % use only for one column version

% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\title{test}

\author{%
\IEEEauthorblockN{test}\\
\IEEEauthorblockA{test}
}



\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    pass
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
test equation,
\begin{equation} \label{eq:eq1}
    2 = 1 + 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:eq2}
3 = 1 + 2
\end{equation}
equation num \eqref{eq:eq1}


\end{document}
```

result:

[image: reference to the section]

without:

```
\documentclass[peerreview]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} % Use the [cmex10] option to ensure complicance
                             % with IEEE Xplore (see bare_conf.tex)
\usepackage{subcaption}
%% Please note that the amsthm package must not be loaded with
%% IEEEtran.cls because IEEEtran provides its own versions of
%% theorems. Also note that IEEEXplore does not accepts submissions
%% with hyperlinks, i.e., hyperref cannot be used.
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath }
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500 % As explained in bare_conf.tex
%%%%%%
% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.48} % use only for one column version

% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\title{test}

\author{%
\IEEEauthorblockN{test}\\
\IEEEauthorblockA{test}
}



\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    pass
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
test equation,
\begin{equation} \label{eq:eq1}
    2 = 1 + 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:eq2}
3 = 1 + 2
\end{equation}
equation num \eqref{eq:eq1}


\end{document}
```

result:

[image: all equations are numbered although only eq (1) is referenced]

Comment: An excerpt from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36312/5001): "The [`cleveref`] package is seriously incompatible with the `showonlyrefs` option of the `mathtools` package. By "seriously incompatible" I mean that if `cleveref` is loaded together with `\usepackage[showonlyrefs]{mathtools}`, not only will the `\cref` commands containing labels of equation objects be messed up, *but many other cross-referencing packages will also experience major problems*" [emphasis added].

Comment: AFAICT, you have two choices: (a) don't load the `cleveref` package, or (b) don't employ the option `showonlyrefs=true` of the `mathtools` package. As an alternative to `showonlyrefs=true`, do consider loading and using the [autonum](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/autonum) package, That package offers features similar to those of `showonlyrefs`, but it does so in a `cleveref`-compatible way.