# Referencing multiple labels at once

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I would like to reference multiple labels in one reference, like it is possible when citing bibliography using the IEEE Standard. When citing, one is able to use:

```
This is a statement \cite{Einstein1910, Newton1700, Moore1950}
```

Which in turn appears as: "This is a statement [1-3]"

Is it possible to use the same mechanism for labels together with the `\ref{}` command?

For example, this input:

```
As seen in figures \ref{fig:apple, fig:pear, fig:fig}
```

Should produce the following output: "As seen in figures 1.1-1.3" or "As seen in figures 1-3".
I tried using the classic `\ref` command, as stated above, but this just resulted in the typical question marks appearing in the output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have a look at the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref?lang=en) package. If you input `\cref{fig:apple,fig:pear,fig:fig}`, it'll output "figures 1 to 3", or whatever numbers apply. (The form of the conjunction can be modified.) If you don't want cleveref to generate the "figures" text prefix automatically, you could write `figures \labelcref{fig:apple,fig:pear,fig:fig}`.

Comment: You should take a look at the `cleveref` package (to be loaded *after* `hyperref`). With `\cref`, you even wouldn't have to type ‘figures’.

Comment: Do also take a look at the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)