# Display of references in a math document

Tags: cross-referencing, amsthm

In a math article one usually writes for a theorem (or proposition or corollary) in latex:

```
\begin{theorem} \label{theorem1}
....

\end{theorem}
```

Now I can reference to this theorem in the article using \ref{theorem1}.
For example I can say:

```
In \ref{theorem1} we saw that .....
```

In the article this will be displayed as (when the theorem has number (lets say) 1.6.)

```
In 1.6 we saw that ....
```

> Question: How can I modify the command \ref{theorem1} so that instead of just "1.6" in the text we see "Theorem 1.6" instead ( Or Proposition or Corollary instead of theorem)?

So the output should be

```
    In Theorem 1.6 we saw that ....
```

Of course I can just write "Theorem" before the "\ref{theorem1}" but I wonder whether there is an automatic way to write the theorem (or propositon or corollary) before the number 1.6.

Comment: Hey @Mare, does `nameref{}` work? Requires the package with the same name and also `hyperref`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: `amsmath` has nothing to do with theorem names.  I'm assuming you meant `amsthm`, and have changed the tag accordingly.

Comment: What’s wrong with typing “Theorem \ref{theorem1}” when you want the “Theorem” to appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two main options:

- Load the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref) package and use its `\autoref` macro instead of the basic `\ref` macro.
- Load the [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package and use its `\cref` macro (instead of `\ref`).

If you load both `hyperref` and `cleveref`, `hyperref` must be loaded first.

For a lot more information about packages that provide various cross-referencing abilities, please see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

A basic MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}  % pick a suitable document class
\usepackage{amsthm}      % or 'ntheorem'
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} \label{theorem1} \dots \end{theorem}

With \verb+\autoref+: \autoref{theorem1}

With \verb+\cref+: \cref{theorem1}
\end{document}
```