# How to cite Lemma/Theorem/Proposition in latex editor?

Tags: cross-referencing

How to cross-reference a Lemma/Theorem/Proposition in TeX Studio?

In the following output, I want to reference Proposition 2.1 in Theorem 2.2:

[image]

I have used the key `\label{p2.1}` in the Proposition 2.1  and then used the key `\eqref{p2.1}` in the Theorem 2.2.

But as shown above there is a bracket enclosing 2.1

[image]

I want to remove the  bracket around `2.1`. I just want to display `2.1` instead of `(2.1)`.

Comment: Off-topic: In the statements of the proposition and the theorem, please don't use text italics where you should be using math italics. E.g., do replace `If A=B then A-B=0` with `If $A=B$ then $A-B=0$`. Similarly, please replace `If A=B then A+C=B+D implies C=D` with `If $A=B$ then $A+C=B+D$ implies $C=D$`. The main difference lies in the spacing around the binary and relational operators such as `+` and `=`.

Comment: For more information on how to create cross-references in a LaTeX document, including information about the `\eqref` command and various LaTeX packages that provide methods that go beyond the basic `\label`-`\ref` mechanism, please see [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

Comment: @Mico, it was an screenshot of pdf output. It is  just for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\eqref` from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is meant to `ref`erence `eq`uations, which typically have their numbering set within some form of enclosed delimiter (like parentheses). Use `\ref` if you only want the number.

If you want to be fancy about it, you could also try

```
\hyperref[p2.1]{Proposition~\ref*{p2.1}}
```

which will make the entire proposition a clickable reference.

Comment: Thank you very much