# Is there a way I can refer to propositions using amsthm?

Tags: cross-referencing, amsthm

I am using `\usepackage{amsthm}` to create propositions. Under my `\begin{document}`, I have

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{alg}[thm]{Algorithm}
```

So if I want to make a proposition in my document, I just wrote `\begin{prop} (stuff) \end{prop}`. So far, everything works great. But suppose I want to refer to a particular proposition (e.g. proposition 2.11). I could just find its assigned number and write it, but if I add new propositions in the future, then the numbering will be all ruined. Is there a way I can assign keywords or something to propositions and write something like "By `\prop{EulersTheorem}`, it follows..."

Comment: Yes, for sure. You have to insert a `\label{}` within the `prop` environment and refer to it using `\ref{}`. Search for cross reference. It is powerful.

Comment: @Sigur This is great. One issue is \ref{} that it only returns the number of that prop. Is there a way to make it return "Prop. 2.7" instead of just "2.7"? Other than that, this helps a lot, thanks. And can it be boldened, or do I have to manually type that?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  As suggested by @sigur, adding a `\label{<name>}` within the environment (if you put it at the beginning, it will be easy to find later) will allow you to use `\ref{<name>}` from anywhere else in your document; you will have to process the document twice to resolve the reference.  You might also find it helpful to read the document for `amsthm` -- `texdoc amsthdoc`.

Comment: You say that your theorem definitions follow `\begin{document}`.  They should be before it, in the preamble.

Comment: In addition to @barbarabeeton nice comment, there is the `cleveref` package to do what you wish about the Prop. names.

Comment: Not meaning to be pesty, but Propositions are part of `amsthm`, not `amsmath`.  I've edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

For a general intro to LaTeX's basic method for creating cross-references and an overview of various cross-referencing packages, please see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) [shameless self-citation alert!].

If you will cross-reference single instances of theorems, lemmas, propositions, etc, all you need to do is load the `cleveref` package and write `\cref{EulersTheorem}` instead of `\ref{EulersTheorem}` in order to get both a name label and the number for the proposition. If there's a chance that you'll create to two or more instances of a theorem, lemma, proposition, etc in one `\cref` directive, it's necessary to inform `cleveref` about the plural forms of the labels via `\crefname` directives. How to do this is shown in the following example document.

[image]

Observe that all cross-references were generated with a single `\cref` statement.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for '\theoremstyle' and '\newtheorem' macros
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

% The following \crefname declarations are needed only
% if your cross-references contain plural items
\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{defn}{definition}{definitions}
\crefname{lem}{lemma}{lemmas} % or 'lemmata'?
\crefname{cor}{corollary}{corollaries} 
\crefname{conj}{conjecture}{conjectures}
\crefname{prop}{proposition}{propositions}
\crefname{alg}{algoirithm}{algorithms}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{alg}[thm]{Algorithm}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{thm}  AAA \label{thm:aaa}  \end{thm}
\begin{defn} BBB \label{defn:bbb} \end{defn}
\begin{lem}  CCC \label{lem:ccc}  \end{lem}
\begin{cor}  DDD \label{cor:ddd}  \end{cor}
\begin{conj} EEE \label{conj:eee} \end{conj}
\begin{prop} FFF \label{prop:fff} \end{prop}
\begin{alg}  GGG \label{alg:ggg}  \end{alg}
\begin{thm}  AAAA \label{thm:aaaa}  \end{thm}
\begin{defn} BBBB \label{defn:bbbb} \end{defn}
\begin{lem}  CCCC \label{lem:cccc}  \end{lem}
\begin{cor}  DDDD \label{cor:dddd}  \end{cor}
\begin{conj} EEEE \label{conj:eeee} \end{conj}
\begin{prop} FFFF \label{EulersTheorem} \end{prop}
\begin{alg}  GGGG \label{alg:gggg}  \end{alg}
\end{multicols}

\noindent
Cross-references to 
\cref{thm:aaa,defn:bbb,lem:ccc,cor:ddd,conj:eee,prop:fff,alg:ggg,%
thm:aaaa,defn:bbbb,lem:cccc,cor:dddd,conj:eeee,EulersTheorem,alg:gggg}.
\end{document}
```