# Bourbaki style "relative"/"conditional" referencing

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to reference the labelled things via their "relative" paths? (This is how Bourbaki referenced in their books.)

More precisely, I am using the `book` with `chapter`s, `section`s and `subsection`s. To maintain simplicity, assume that everything is numbered. The following cases illustrate what I want:

1. References to Chapter 1 from within the same chapter should be "this chapter" and those from other places should be "Chapter 1".
2. References to Chapter 1's Section 2 from within the same section should be "this section", those from Chapter 1's any other places within Chapter 1 should be "Section 2", and those from the remaining paces should be "Section 2 of Chapter 1".
3. References to Chapter 1's Section 2's Subsection 3 from within the same subsection should be "this subsection", those from other places within Chapter 1's Section 2 should be "Subsection 3", those from other places within Chapter 1 should be "Subsection 3 of Section 2", and those from the remaining places should be "Subsection 3 of Section 2 of Chapter 1".

---

Further, let's say I have `theorem`s (via `amsthm`) interspersed throughout (they needn't occur only in `subsection`s) numbered within `section`. I want the references to Theorem 2.1 (which occurs in Chapter 1's Section 2's Subsection 3) from within Chapter 1 to be called "Theorem 2.1", and from any other places to be called "Theorem 2.1 of Chapter 1".

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you know [the `varioref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref). Somehow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33017/277964 could also be related.

Comment: [`zref-check`](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref-check) can assist you with some of your requirements. (Though not all, and even in those in which it can, it offers just some support to keep consistency rather than proper automation).

Comment: Yes you can do that. You only need to record enough data and then implement the logic. See eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325319/2388 for something similar where zref was used (today I would use properties but they didn't exist at that time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof of concept as you won't get warnings if the labels are wrong.

<sub>This style of references is very heavy and not a good service to your readers, in my opinion.</sub>

```
\documentclass{book}

\NewProperty{chapter}{now}{0}{\arabic{chapter}}
\NewProperty{section}{now}{0}{\arabic{section}}
\NewProperty{subsection}{now}{0}{\arabic{subsection}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterlabel}{m}{%
  \label{ch:#1}%
  \RecordProperties{ch@:#1}{chapter}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sectionlabel}{m}{%
  \label{sec:#1}%
  \RecordProperties{sec@:#1}{chapter,section}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\subsectionlabel}{m}{%
  \label{subsec:#1}%
  \RecordProperties{subsec@:#1}{chapter,section,subsection}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapref}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \property_ref:nn { ch@:#1 } { chapter } } { \arabic{chapter} }
   {
    this~chapter
   }
   {
    chapter\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { ch@:#1 } { chapter }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\secref}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \property_ref:nn { sec@:#1 } { chapter } } { \arabic{chapter} }
   {% we're in the same chapter
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \property_ref:nn { sec@:#1 } { section } } { \arabic{section} }
     {% we're in the same section
      this~section
     }
     {% different section, same chapter
      section\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { sec@:#1 } { section }
     }
   }
   {% different chapter
    section\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { sec@:#1 } { section }~
    of~chapter\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { sec@:#1 } { chapter }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\subsecref}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { chapter } } { \arabic{chapter} }
   {% we're in the same chapter
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { section } } { \arabic{section} }
     {% we're in the same section
      \str_if_eq:eeTF { \property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { subsection } } { \arabic{subsection} }
       {% we're in the same subsection
        this~subsection
       }
       {% different subsection, same section
        subsection\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { subsection }
       }
     }
     {% different section, same chapter
      subsection\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { subsection }~
      of~section\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { section }
     }
   }
   {% different chapter
    subsection\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { subsection }~
    of~section\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { section }~
    of~chapter\nobreakspace\property_ref:nn { subsec@:#1 } { chapter }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
  

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}\chapterlabel{testchapter1}

\chapref{testchapter1} --- \chapref{testchapter2}

\section{Test}\sectionlabel{testsection1}

\subsection{Test}\subsectionlabel{testsubsection1}

\section{Second}\sectionlabel{testsection2}

A: \secref{testsection1}. B: \secref{testsection2}. C: \secref{testsection3}

\subsection{AAA}\subsectionlabel{testsubsection2}

A: \subsecref{testsubsection1}.
B: \subsecref{testsubsection2}.
C: \subsecref{testsubsection3}.

\chapter{Second}\chapterlabel{testchapter2}

\section{Again}\sectionlabel{testsection3}

\subsection{BBB}\subsectionlabel{testsubsection3}

\end{document}
```

We record more properties for a single `\...label` and so we're able to check them one by one.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I do have a suggestion though. Why not use the `label` hook to set the properties in a single auxiliary label and use just `\label` all around instead of relying on the `\chapterlabel`, `\sectionlabel`, `\subsectionlabel` complexity?

Comment: Going through your answer. It turns out that `\NewProperty` is a recent addition to LaTeX. Is it properly documented somewhere (apart from so that I can understand what it does?

Comment: @Atom `texdoc ltproperties`

Comment: @gusbrs I hope the OP doesn’t want something like “equation 3 of subsection 4 of section 7 of chapter 11”

Comment: Thanks! Feels so cool to use the recent additions to LaTeX kernel! (And yeah, I intend to keep it to "Eqn 3 of Sec 7.4 of Chap 11" ;)

Comment: Also, in your opinion, where do I start learning `expl3` to be able to understand your code?

Comment: @egreg :-) :-).

Comment: @Atom `texdoc interface3`. Sorry, but I won't help you along this road that I find really awful.

Comment: Is there a reason why you used `@` while recording new properties?

Comment: @Atom You can't have the same label twice, one for `\label` and one for `\RecordProperties`.

Comment: So, `\RecordProperties` records properties to a "separate label" called `ch@:#1`? If so, what's the purpose of having `\label{ch:#1}` inside the definition of `\chapterlabel`?

Comment: @Atom In case you change your mind… 

Comment: Finally, I understand the ins and outs of your programme. :D Moving forward, I wish to combine the `\chapref`, `\secref`, `\subsecref` into a single command as I describe [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708235/207649). You think you can help?