# Automatically insert "in the next [chapter/section/subsection]" if reference is sequential

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I'm aware of the cleveref package `\cref` which adds the correct reference name (see: 
[Automatically inserting "Section", "Subsection", etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39349/automatically-inserting-section-subsection-etc)). I have a few references which refer to the very next section and some find it odd to give the number in this case rather than just say "in the next section". Sometimes I've moved sections around and these references suddenly become quite broken. To have the best of both worlds, is there a way to automate this change?

E.g.: replace "this is discussed further in ***section 1.4***" with "this is discussed further in ***the next section***"

Comment: So you would basically like a command that outputs *in the next section* when the referenced *section* is immediately following the current *section*, and other wise output *section 3.4*?

Comment: @Karalga exactly (or whatever number the reference would normally be :P).

Comment: @jozxyqk: There is some related content on this site. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33017/8057 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32478/8057

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution based on `cleveref` package. If the `hyperref` package is loaded, the word "section" (or chapter/subsection/...) is a clickable hyperlink.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}

\providecommand\hyperref[2][]{#2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mt@ref}[1]{%
\cref@gettype{#1}{\@temptype}%
\cref@getcounter{#1}{\@tempctr}%
\def\mtt{\the\csname c@\@temptype\endcsname}%
\ifnum\mtt=\numexpr\@tempctr-1\relax \mtcase the next \hyperref[#1]{\@temptype}\else%
\ifnum\mtt=\numexpr\@tempctr+1\relax \mtcase the previous \hyperref[#1]{\@temptype}\else%
\cref{#1}\fi\fi}

\newcommand{\mtref}{\let\mtcase\relax\mt@ref}
\newcommand{\Mtref}{\let\mtcase\MakeUppercase\mt@ref}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Foo}\label{sec:foo}
this is \Mtref{sec:bar} and this is \mtref{sec:baz}
\subsection{Sub foo}\label{ss:sfoo}
this is \mtref{sec:baz} and this is \mtref{sec:bar}
and \mtref{ss:sfbla} and \mtref{ss:sfbaz}
\subsection{Bla foo}\label{ss:sfbla}
bla bla bla
\subsection{Bar foo}\label{ss:sfbar}
bla bla bla
\subsection{Baz foo}\label{ss:sfbaz}
bla bla bla
\section{Bar}\label{sec:bar}
bla bla bla
\section{Baz}\label{sec:baz}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

The result looks approximately like this (compiled with a previous version of the code):

[image: Result of compilation]

Comment: I didn't mention it explicitly in my question, but hyperref and cleveref are two packages I'm using too. I like your solution, and I'll try it soon.

Comment: This works like a charm, also the hyperref links -- thanks a lot! I changed two things in my local copy: 1. I write "the next" instead of "next", because "in the next subsection" should be substituted with "in subsection x.y". 2. I extended the code to include the case "previous section". I can edit your answer if you like.

Comment: @krlmlr please feel free.

Comment: A command `\Mtref` (in the same spirit as `\Cref`) seems to be necessary, too. I copy-pasted the definition, but perhaps there's a nicer solution?

Comment: @ what do you want to uppercase `The next section?` or `the next Section?`

Comment: "The next section" -- at the beginning of the sentence (just like `\Cref`).

Comment: @krlmlr answer updated

Answer (score 9):

### Revised Attempt

In addition to `\Unitref{<label>}` which provides the unit name along with the ref, as in "section 2" or "subsection 1.1", etc. (see original attempt), I now also introduce `\Ref{<unit>}{<label>}`, where `<unit>` is what is to be compared, "section", "subsection", or "subsubsection".  If `\ref{<label>}` is, in fact, the next increment of the unit, it will output "the next ".  If `\ref{<label>}` is not the next increment of the unit, it will output " `\ref{<label>}`".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\let\svsection\section
\let\svsubsection\subsection
\let\svsubsubsection\subsubsection

\def\section{\xdef\Unit{section}\svsection}
\def\subsection{\xdef\Unit{subsection}\svsubsection}
\def\subsubsection{\xdef\Unit{subsubsection}\svsubsubsection}

\let\svlabel\label
\def\label#1{\expandafter\xdef\csname Unit-#1\endcsname{\Unit}\svlabel{#1}}

\def\Unitref#1{\csname Unit-#1\endcsname~\ref{#1}}

\def\thenextsection{\the\numexpr\thesection+1\relax}
\def\thenextsubsection{\thesection.\the\numexpr\arabic{subsection}+1\relax}
\def\thenextsubsubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}%
  .\the\numexpr\arabic{subsubsection}+1\relax}

\def\Ref#1#2{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\ref{#2}}{\csname thenext#1\endcsname}}%
  {the next #1}{#1~\ref{#2}}
}
\begin{document}

\section{The First Section\label{s:first}}

``The First Subsection'' is \Ref{subsection}{ss:first},
whereas ``The Second Subsection'' is \Ref{subsection}{ss:second}.

\subsection{The First Subsection\label{ss:first}}

In the prior unit, \Unitref{s:first}, not to be confused with the 
current unit, \Unitref{ss:first}, we have successfully captured the data

``A Subsubsection'' is \Ref{subsubsection}{sss:first},
whereas ``Second Subsubsection'' is \Ref{subsubsection}{sss:second}.

\subsubsection{A subsubsection\label{sss:first}}

``The First Section'' is \Ref{section}{s:first},
whereas ``The Second Section'' is \Ref{section}{s:second}.

\section{The Second Section\label{s:second}}

\subsection{The Section Subsection\label{ss:second}}

The prior unit, \Unitref{s:second} is not to be confused with the 
way back references to either \Unitref{s:first}, \Unitref{ss:first},
or \Unitref{sss:first}. But the current unit is \Unitref{ss:second}.
We have successfully captured the data.

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection\label{sss:second}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Areas that need improvement include optional capitalization of the "unit" name, if appearing at the beginning of a sentence, for example.  Also, `\Ref` can only compare "apples and apples".  That is, if the label is that of a subsection, `\Ref` can only be used to see if it is the next subsection, which is why argument `#1` of `\Ref` has to currently be specified explicitly.

### Original (misguided) attempt

Here I just played around a little in the preamble and created `\Unitref{}` to get "section 2" or "subsection 1.1", etc.

What I do is save the name "section", "subsection", etc. in a macro `\Unit` whenever I enter such a unit.  Then, when invoking `\label`, I use the current value of `\Unit` as the value of a new macro `\csname Unit-<label>\endcsname`.

Finally, when invoking `\Unitref{<label>}`, it calls upon `\csname Unit-<label>\endcsname` and follows up with a hard space and a call to `\ref{<label>}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svsection\section
\let\svsubsection\subsection
\let\svsubsubsection\subsubsection

\def\section{\xdef\Unit{section}\svsection}
\def\subsection{\xdef\Unit{subsection}\svsubsection}
\def\subsubsection{\xdef\Unit{subsubsection}\svsubsubsection}

\let\svlabel\label
\def\label#1{\expandafter\xdef\csname Unit-#1\endcsname{\Unit}\svlabel{#1}}

\def\Unitref#1{\csname Unit-#1\endcsname~\ref{#1}}
\begin{document}

\section{The First Section\label{s:first}}

\subsection{First Subsection\label{ss:first}}

In the prior unit, \Unitref{s:first}, not to be confused with the 
current unit, \Unitref{ss:first}, we have successfully captured the data

\subsubsection{A subsubsection\label{sss:first}}

Blah-Blah

\section{The Next Section\label{s:second}}

\subsection{Next Subsection\label{ss:second}}

The prior unit, \Unitref{s:second} is not to be confused with the 
way back references to either \Unitref{s:first}, \Unitref{ss:first},
or \Unitref{sss:first}. But the current unit is \Unitref{ss:second}.
We have successfully captured the data.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, in my opinion...

Comment: @Werner  What was I thinking?  I'll delete in a bit.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: No, please don't! I think this can be a key step to solving the issue -- the only remaining bit is to detect that 2.2.3 is the section after 2.2.2 and before 2.2.4, but not related to 2.3.x or 1.2.y. (Or am I mistaken? Can you use `\Unitref` to produce the number of the **current** section?)

Comment: @krlmlr Please see my revision.  It is much closer to what you seek.

Comment: If for some reason you want to change the section numbering to something else than a arabic number, e.g. `\renewcommand*\thesection{\Roman{section}}`, the code can't process the comparisons properly anymore. The OP does not give a clue about that and thinking of future readers you could (possibly) robustify this alredy good solution by comparing `\c@...`'s rather than `\the...`'s.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I decided to award the bounty to @touhami for better interop with cleveref and hyperref.

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

The basic LaTeX `\label` mechanism, which the `cleveref` package uses to generate its output, stores only two characteristics associated with an "item" (such as a section, equation, theorem, etc): the item's *number* -- more precisely, the value of whatever counter value was most recently incremented via a `\refstepcounter` instruction -- and the *number of the page* on which the item's number is output.

Unfortunately, because `\label` doesn't capture other item characteristics -- such as the chapter, section, or subsection number -- you can't use `\cref` to create a call-out of the type "in the next section" (instead of "in section 1.4") if the cross-referencing call-out happens to occur in section 1.3.

You may want to look into the [zref package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) to build an enhanced cross-referencing functionality of the type you describe.

Comment: But the full section number is stored at least in the `.aux` file. Is there no way to access it from there? I don't really see why the desired functionality is impossible, or how `zref` can help here.