# Design size mismatch warning when using the eco package

Tags: fontsize, warnings, oldstylenums

I'm using the [`eco` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eco) and am getting the following warning:

```
design size mismatch in local font ecrm2074 in virtual font ecorm2074.vf ignored.
```

when compiling the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{eco}

\begin{document}
  {\huge This causes a warning}
\end{document}
```

the warning goes away if I don't use `\huge` (or `eco`).

Any ideas as to how I can get rid of it?

Comment: `\huge` is a font switch and not a command with arguments. You should use `{\huge text}` instead of `\huge{text}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: changed it, same warning though...

Comment: Yes, I know that the message will still be there. My previous comment was only meant to correct the use of `\huge`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: thanks anyway :) I never thought about it not being a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "design size mismatch" is issued by TeX when it loads font `ecorm2074` which is a virtual font; this means that it's a container of references to other fonts. When TeX loads this font it realizes that the referenced fonts are loaded with a size parameter that differs from what's stated in the fonts themselves.

Judging from line 156 in `create.sh` in the sources of `eco` fonts, the recorded size parameter is 20.74, while the referenced fonts (`ecrm2074` and `tcrm2074`) carry 20.7400055.

At such a big size, rounding errors can be expected. The same happens with

- `ecorm1728`: 17.28 against 17.279999
- `ecorm1440`: 14.40 against 14.399994

but not with `ecorm1200` and smaller sizes.

When I run `vftovp` on the offending `.vf` files, the program says

```
Design size in VF file being replaced by TFM design size
```

The same happens when TeX loads the font and actually corrects the mismatching entry: the difference is very small, so nothing relevant happens.

However this should be regarded as a (small) bug in the `eco` distribution.

One can regenerate the `.vf` files with the help of a Bash script: create a directory called, say, `ecocorrected` and in it put the following `regenerate.sh` script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/public/eco/*
do
  j=$(basename $i)
  vftovp $i > ${j%.*}.vpl
done
for i in *.vpl
do
  vptovf $i
done
rm -i *.tfm *.vpl
```

Run the following shell commands

```bsh
cd ecocorr
bash regenerate.sh
```

Then the `ecocorrected` directory can be moved in the correct place:

```bsh
mv regenerate.sh ..
cd ..
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/vf/public
sudo mv ecocorrected /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/vf/public
sudo mktexlsr
```

When and if the `eco` distribution will be corrected, you can remove the `ecocorrected` directory (and rerun `mktexlsr`).

Actually, running this procedure tells that the `eco` distribution has several little annoyances, which shouldn't be ignored, but are not very harmful anyway. Personally, I'd live with the warnings, though

Comment: That was illuminating :) Any idea how I can fix this small bug? (I'm an absolute illiterate in fonts, font encodings and the like).

Comment: @mpr All `.vf` files for sizes from 14.4 upward should be regenerated with the correct design size. Just live with the innocuous message until someone corrects the small bug. Or regenerate the `.vf` files yourself.

Comment: Is there any way I can contribute and upload the corrected versions (assuming I get them to work)? if so... how?

Comment: I would contact the maintainer of the `eco` package.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to put into a comment, and also only a partial answer. Switching to a different compiler solves the problem. Perhaps others may have an idea based on the following:

- Compiling with `pdflatex` produces the "design size mismatch" font warning. `pdffonts` produces:

  ```
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  ZLOGBE+SFRM1000                      Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
  WPERDS+SFRM2074                      Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
  ```
- Compiling with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` does NOT produce the warning. `pdffonts` produces:

  ```
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  MPHKJZ+SFRM2074                      Type 1C           yes yes no      10  0
  OTJKZH+SFRM1000                      Type 1C           yes yes no       8  0
  ```
- Compiling with `xelatex` does NOT produce produce the warning. `pdffonts` produces:

  ```
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  VSQWHV+SFRM1000                      Type 1C           yes yes no       4  0
  RQEQJE+SFRM2074                      Type 1C           yes yes no       5  0
  ```

It is clearly the font encoding. As such, switching to [Latin Modern](http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) fonts (via `\usepackage{lmodern}`) also avoids this problem with the following `pdffonts` outputs:

- Compiling with `pdflatex`, `pdffonts` produces:

  ```
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  JVWJQI+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
  NHHVPB+LMRoman17-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
  ```
- Compiling with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`, `pdffonts` produces:

  ```
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  MPHKJZ+LMRoman17-Regular             Type 1C           yes yes no      10  0
  OTJKZH+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1C           yes yes no       8  0
  ```
- Compiling with `xelatex`, `pdffonts` produces:

  ```
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  VYDDOZ+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1C           yes yes no       4  0
  ICNJUT+LMRoman17-Regular             Type 1C           yes yes no       5  0
  ```

Comment: I fear I lack the TeXpertise to fully comprehend your answer... What's `pdffonts`? Why do different toolchains produce different encodings? How can I ask for a particular one (I'm guessing `1C`) in the offending line?

Comment: I am also very unfamiliar with font encodings, hence my "non-answer" answer. However, it showed that switching to (say) [`lmodern`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodern/) is a possibility. `pdffonts` is a command-line program that outputs information on fonts contained within a PDF.

Comment: indeed switching to `lmodern` solves the issue... but I lose oldstyle numbers with it. Maybe unrelated, but I get `Argument of strip@CM@prefix@ has an extra }` errors when using `lmodern` with `mmap` (the error comes from `mmap`).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've got it now:

The [`eco` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eco) somehow messes up the fonts and trouble arises with certain combination of sizes, shapes and weights. In this particular case, the problems where in the title pages and on the part headings.

Luckily, I was already using the [`sectsty` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) and managed to get out of the latter with:

```
\partfont{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}
```

(the `\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont` "trick" I learned from [another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/oldstyle-numbers-in-body-newstyle-numbers-in-section-headings)).

For the title pages it was enough to say `\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont` where appropriate.

Hope this helps someone else trying to get rid of that pesky little warnings!